# Uninstall without an MSI file

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I often get a problem with Windows Installer trying to uninstall a package, but it complains that:

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable.

Is there a known means of uninstalling such packages when the original MSI is simply not available?

Comment: See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933) for a list of ways to uninstall MSI packages.

Comment: See [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall/1189524#1189524) for a **comprehensive explanation** of the cause of the problem (see the answer below too).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at a tool called <del>[MSIZap](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301)</del> released by Microsoft.

---

**UPDATE**:

**MsiZap.exe** has been deprecated for quite some time. Its use is unsupported on all recent versions of Windows, and it is considered a very **unsafe tool to use**.

I added a link to a newer Microsoft support tool designed to clean out installations, but this tool also appears deprecated at this point. I have removed the link from the comments section.

Perhaps try the tool linked to in **[saschabeaumont's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334490/uninstall-without-an-msi-file/11058378#11058378)** answer below.

Comment: MSIZAP === BAD! See http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/3/6/More-on-Haacks-Troubleshooting-Windows-MSI-Installers for more information on why .

Comment: Unfortunately this tool is no longer available from Microsoft. Saying 'MSIZAP == BAD' is all very well but that hardly solves the problem, does it? It's just unhelpful to say something is bad without providing an alternative.

Comment: The new tool is not supported by Windows 8.

Answer (score 62):

Please note that Microsoft has now released an official tool to resolve these issues, without the problems that previously existed with MSIZAP.

- Microsoft Fixit: [Fix problems with programs that can't be installed or uninstalled](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)

Comment: since then it became deprecated

Comment: This works great. Lists a huge raft of 'old' apps that are clearly still handing around on your system. It does work.

Comment: For those who try this tool, please report back here whether it actually worked or not.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul yep, works great. It allow me to uninstall jetbrains tray notifier tool which hasn't msi installer

Comment: After Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, I could not install a newer version of Futuremark SystemInfo (comes with 3DMark) because it was failing on uninstalling the previous one, because the .msi was missing. This application fixed the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This tool did a great job, however, it can only repair one product at a time, and it takes a while. I have the problem that I have several corrupted installations, is there a batch-version available?

Comment: Worked on Windows 10 where CCleaner has failed.

Comment: The link above failed for me but googling "Microsoft Fixit" led to the uninstall helper/fixit tool.

Comment: the MS fixer works, it does takes time though, about 10-15 minutes!!

Comment: this works! managed to install Microsoft.Azure.Compute.Emulator.Exe 2.9.5.2

Comment: The tool worked for me, thank you. Removed AWS CLI after the original .msi was lost.

Answer (score 7):

FYI, this post explains the root problem  https://superuser.com/q/293542/245923

You can uninstall it using the product code:

```
msiexec.exe /x {your-product-code-guid}
```

You would obtain this code from the MSI itself, or whatever tool you are using to build the MSI.

Note that when you uninstall a product, it uses a cached MSI, since only the original MSI knows how to uninstall itself. When you use the product code, it uses the cached MSI from C:\WINDOWS\Installer.

Comment: This pops up asking me to locate the msi file

Comment: this is doing the same thing as the Uninstall Programs and Features is doing

Answer (score 4):

> ***Update, Stein Åsmul***: [**There is a whole list of cleanup approaches here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876550/wix-custom-action-dialogbox-on-silent-uninstall-of-application/53876981#53876981) (recommended).

---

**UPDATE**:

<del>[**This newer support tool**](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;290301)</del> can be tried on recent Windows versions if you have **defunct MSI packages needing uninstall**. *This new tool appears to have been deprecated as well.*

Perhaps try the tool linked to in **[saschabeaumont's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334490/uninstall-without-an-msi-file/11058378#11058378)** answer.

---

**It is not normal or standard MSI behavior to ask for the original source media - it indicates a badly designed MSI package.** If you experience this with a vendor MSI it is highly recommended that you report the problem to their support team. Here is a **more comprehensive explanation** of the problem: **[Why does MSI require the original .msi file to proceed with an uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208530/why-does-msi-require-the-original-msi-file-to-proceed-with-an-uninstall/1189524#1189524)**

In most cases MSI packages can be uninstalled from **add/remove programs** from the **control panel** even if you don't have the original installation database for the MSI - the uninstall is run from a cached copy of the original MSI in the system folder **%SystemRoot%\Windows\Installer** (in some cases this cached MSI could be missing, [**see section 12 here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933) for potential causes).

Earlier versions of MSI tended to trigger this problem (asking for the original installation media) more often (Office back in the day), and legacy MSI files can still cause uninstall problems that can only be solved using the <del>**msizap.exe** tool</del> (this tool is **deprecated**, **outdated** and **no longer supported**). This command line tool (<del>msizap.exe</del>) also had a GUI available (<del>MSICUU2.exe</del>), both tools are deprectated (try the link to the new cleanup tool listed above).

Just for the record: If you have access to the **original MSI** that was actually used to install the product, you can use this to run the uninstall. It must be **the exact MSI that was used**, and not just a similar one. There is a **unique package guid** assigned to each MSI file, so Windows will know if  it is the right one.

Related answers:

- [wix - custom action dialogbox on silent uninstall of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876550/wix-custom-action-dialogbox-on-silent-uninstall-of-application/53876981#53876981)
- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't do something crazy like go to C:\Windows\Installer\ and delete the files in there did you?

One drawback of MSI files is you need the complete MSI file in order to uninstall or repair the application.  Windows loves to store a copy of the MSI. It also renames the MSI file from a common name to a GUID with no table (that I can find) to map original names (example: `Office2010.msi`) to the new GUID so you have a PC with many GBs of wasted space that you can't delete. A machine that's not even 1 year old can easily hit 8 GB (example: mine).

Comment: Incorrect, the MSI database itself it usually only a few MB at most once embedded CAB files are extracted. Only the MSI without the CAB files is usually cached on the system

Comment: I second sascha here, the MSI cached in C:\Windows\Installer is a stripped down version of the installer MSI without CABS. This cached copy is used for repair / uninstall after installation. The source media is only needed if the repair needs to reinstall files or if the MSI is badly designed and runs operations that "asks for" the original source.

As far as I understand future versions of MSI will cache the entire MSI before installation occurs.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul why not remove one of the duplicated comments

Comment: Even if the MSI files are gutted, they still occupy 4GB of data as is, and another 3GB was in my "$PatchCache" folder, which you can safely flush (unless you ever plan on removing a patch, which never happens).  It's not like I have hundreds of programs installed.  Despite this cache is massive and a waste of HD.

Comment: There has been a change in how MSI files are cached, starting with Windows 7 (MSI version 5) the MSI files are now cached full size to avoid breaking the file signature that affects the UAC prompt on setup launch (a known Vista problem). This may cause a tremendous increase in disk space consumption (several gigabytes for some systems).

Answer (score 1):

There is an MSI cleanup utility from Microsoft, <del>*[Windows Installer Cleanup Utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301)*</del> (**deprecated** tool, **unsupported** and **unsafe** to use - perhaps try this answer instead: [Uninstall without an MSI file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334490/uninstall-without-an-msi-file/11058378#11058378)).

Or [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) can usually do this

Comment: no no no no no ... it leaves your system in a dirty state. See http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/3/6/More-on-Haacks-Troubleshooting-Windows-MSI-Installers for more info.

Comment: That post doesn't explain what to do if you didn't leave multiple Gb of MSI output in some GUID labeled folder on your machine.

Comment: Here is the corrected link for the Rob Mensching blog post.
https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/3/6/more-on-haacks-troubleshooting-windows-msi-installers/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the MSI package but an *.exe installer of the exact same version of the software that you want to uninstall, you can do this:

1. Run the installer exe.
2. If you are provided with the option to "remove" the software, try it.
   Otherwise:
3. Open Windows Explorer and navigate to
   `%LocalAppdata%\Temp\`
4. Sort by date and search in the latest created folders for an MSI file that could belong to the software that you want to uninstall.
5. Copy the path of that folder.
6. Go to "Apps and Features" and uninstall the software.
7. In the dialog that complains about network drive, click "Browse..."
8. Paste/navigate the folder to the address bar and select the available MSI package.
9. Confirm everything and proceed with the uninstallation.

If an error appears, you have run the installer of the wrong version in step 1.

Answer (score -4):

Control Panel --> Add/Remove programs?

**EDIT:**
Your post mentions nothing about using add remove programs to uninstall the app, you said the "Windows Installer" (MSIEXEC - see the link below), which is not the same thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(VS.85).aspx

Comment: That is where my problem starts.

Comment: Uninstall uses the provided uninstaller which is an usually an MSI.

Comment: I didn't vote you down, but I thought I pretty much implied what epchwolf says.

Comment: BTW, if it needs an MSI file, I think it's pretty damn obvious that it's Windows Installer.