# Batch file to get specific installed software along with version

Tags: batch-file

I have a script which finds specific installed software but I am having trouble also getting the software's version. For example, say I am getting a list of all Microsoft software installed. Here is what I have thus far:

```
echo software installed > software_list.txt
echo ================= >>software_list.txt
reg export HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall temp1.txt
find "Microsoft" temp1.txt| find "DisplayName" > temp2.txt
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims==" %%a in (temp2.txt) do (echo %%a >> software_list.txt)

start notepad "software_list.txt"

del temp1.txt temp2.txt
```

How can I also get the DisplayVersion from the reg export? If I replace DisplayName with DisplayVersion, nothing is even found. Or, is there another avenue I should be taking here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replacing `DisplayName` with `DisplayVersion` results in an empty output because of the way this line works:

```
find "Microsoft" temp1.txt| find "DisplayName" > temp2.txt
```

What this line does is it finds all lines in the `temp2.txt` file that contain both the *Microsoft* and *DisplayName* substrings (that is, it finds the products whose names contain *Microsoft*). The lines with *DisplayVersion*, in their turn, contain product version numbers and don't contain the word *Microsoft*, which is why you get empty output.

I can suggest a couple of alternative solutions that use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx):

1. Parse the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` subkeys using a script (VBScript, PowerShell etc) rather than a batch file, because scripting languages offer much better support for text manipulation. Here's a VBScript example that outputs the names and versions of installed Microsoft products (products whose names contain *Microsoft*, to be more precise):

   ```
   On Error Resume Next

   Const strComputer = "."
   Const HKLM        = &H80000002
   Const strKeyPath  = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

   Dim oReg, arrSubKeys, strProduct, strDisplayName, strVersion

   Set oReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
        strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

   ' Enumerate the subkeys of the Uninstall key
   oReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKeyPath, arrSubKeys
   For Each strProduct In arrSubKeys
     ' Get the product's display name
     oReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKeyPath & "\" & strProduct, "DisplayName", strDisplayName
     ' Process only products whose name contain 'Microsoft'
     If InStr(1, strDisplayName, "Microsoft", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       ' Get the product's display version
       oReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKeyPath & "\" & strProduct, "DisplayVersion", strVersion
       WScript.Echo strDisplayName & vbTab & strVersion
     End If
   Next
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   cscript //nologo productlist.vbs
   cscript //nologo productlist.vbs > productlist.txt
   ```
2. If the software you're interested in is installed by the [Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc185688.aspx), you can get info about that software (such as the name, vendor, version etc) by querying the WMI [`Win32_Product`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378.aspx) class. The `wmic` utility lets you do this directly from the command line and batch files. Here're some examples:

   - Print the names and versions of installed software:

     ```
     wmic product get Name, Version
     ```
   - List all installed Microsoft products:

     ```
     wmic product where "Vendor like '%Microsoft%'" get Name, Version
     ```
   - List installed products that have *Office* in their names:

     ```
     wmic product where "Name like '%Office%'" get Name, Version
     ```

   To save the `wmic` output to a file, you can use the `/output` and (optionally) `/format` parameters, e.g.:

   ```
   wmic /output:software.txt product get Name, Version
   wmic /output:software.htm product get Name, Version /format:htable
   ```

   For more information about the `wmic` syntax, see `wmic /?`

Comment: Is there a way to get the installation path of a program installed by Window Installer ? My program is an Interop Excel Addin, only containing .dlls and no executables .exe. It is seen my Add/Remove program and _wmic product get Name, Version_ listing but not by command _where_

Comment: @Kenny: Try the `InstallLocation` property, e.g. `wmic get Name, InstallLocation`.

Comment: Unfortunately InstallLocation is empty. I have the impression that _wmic_ get information from _HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall_ due to the similar list of properties. You can also see from this reg entry that many have _InstallLocation _missing.

Comment: @Kenny, I would suggest [asking this as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: x86 apps not listed or may be only for "Google Chrome"

Answer (score 2):

**[Shamelessly copy/pasted @Helen's answer starts here]**

If the software you're interested in is installed by the Windows Installer, you can get info about that software (such as the name, vendor, version etc) by querying the WMI Win32_Product class. In batch files, this can be done using the WMI command-line utility wmic. Here're some examples:

```
*

  Print the names and versions of installed software:

  wmic product get Name, Version

*

  List all installed Microsoft products:

  wmic product where "Vendor like '%Microsoft%'" get Name, Version

*

  List installed products that have Office in their names:

  wmic product where "Name like '%Office%'" get Name, Version
```

To save the wmic output to a file, you can use the /output and/or /format parameters, e.g.:

wmic /output:software.txt product get Name, Version
wmic /output:software.htm product get Name, Version /format:htable

For more information about the wmic syntax, see wmic /?

**[End of shamelessly copy/pasted answer from @Helen ends here.]**

If the software wasnt' installed by Windows Installer, rather than look in the registry, you could look in the exes themselves.  You need something beyond a mere .bat file.   You need something that can open the exes and extract the version info.

I would take a look at [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx), which is windows successor to .bat files.   Use System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo to get the version.

Answer (score 1):

similar script working for a range of computers "Array"

```
On Error Resume Next

    Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
    Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
    'What Programm to look for
    Const strProgram = "Microsoft"

    arrComputers = Array("NAME1","Name2")
    For Each strComputer In arrComputers
       WScript.Echo
       WScript.Echo "=========================================="
       WScript.Echo "Computer: " & strComputer
       WScript.Echo "=========================================="

       Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
       Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name like '%" & strProgram & "%'")

       For Each objItem In colItems
          WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name & ";" & "Version: " & objItem.Version
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility beyond PowerShell (which is a good one) is to use WMI with JScript or VBScript to access the software store.