# Cmake is not recognized as an internal or external command. How to check the version of cmake installed using windows command prompt

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, cmake

How to check whether the cmake is installed in my windows 8.1 PC using command line. I am getting the error when I am running the windows batch file 
"'cmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." 
Please help for this . 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to get specific installed software along with version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482739/batch-file-to-get-specific-installed-software-along-with-version)

Comment: Does a portable installation count? If so, all you can really do is scan the entire filsystem for cmake.exe, which is potentially very slow and definitely annoying. Else go with Florian's suggestion. Or else just make sure cmake is in the PATH or in a known location.

Comment: Thanks to all .. Actually it was installed but corrupted .. Now its working . Once again thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if cmake is installed in your windows PC using command line, try to run the cmake command in a prompt: if you have the error you quoted in your question, it's not installed. Note that it doesn't mean cmake isn't effectively installed. It may be installed, but the path to the cmake executable may not have been added to your PATH environment variable: the command line will not be able to find the executable.