# Retrieve Outlook Version number and Type(32/64 bit) through a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, outlook

I need to find the Outlook Version number and Type(32/64 bit) through a batch file.
How can this be retrieved through the command line in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

```
wmic product where "Name like '%%Outlook%%'" get Version | findstr /r /v "^$" > temp2.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a (temp2.txt) (echo %%a)
```

reference: [Batch file to get specific installed software along with version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482739/batch-file-to-get-specific-installed-software-along-with-version)
the above code to get version number.

Comment: 1. wmic shows only product installed via windows installer. 
2. on a side note, if you tried the first line from command line and not putting inside a batch file you might not get desired results. %% will escape to % only side a batch file not in prompt.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way using the registry:

```cmd
@Echo Off

If "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%"=="86" (If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
        Set "Key=\Wow6432Node" & Set "MWB=64") Else (Set "MWB=32" & Set "MOB=32"
    )) Else Set "MWB=64"
Set "KEY=HKLM\Software%KEY%\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" 

Set "GUID="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Reg Query %KEY% /K /F "*-001A-*0FF1CE}"') Do (
    If Not Defined GUID Set "GUID=%%~nxA")
If Not "%GUID:~-1%"=="}" Set "GUID="
If Not Defined GUID (Echo= Unable to find Outlook Product & GoTo EndIt)

If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 4 Set "IOV=10" Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 2 (Set "IOV=07"
    If Not Defined MOB Set "MOB=32") Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 5 (Set "IOV=13"
        ) Else (If %GUID:~4,1% Equ 6 Set "IOV=16")))

If Not Defined IOV (Echo= Unknown Outlook version on your %MWB%-bit OS
    GoTo EndIt)

If Not Defined MOB Set "MOB=32"
If %GUID:~20,1% Equ 1 Set "MOB=64"

Echo=&Echo= Outlook 20%IOV% %MOB%-bit Product installed on a %MWB%-bit OS

:EndIt
Timeout 5 1>Nul
```

*This has not been tested because I have never been able to justify the cost of any Microsoft Office product.*