# Is there a "best" way to forcibly "uninstall" a product when the MSI fails during uninstall?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

My install fails on uninstall because of a bug in my CustomAction. I've fixed the bug, but I now have a test machine with that product installed and I can't get it to uninstall (keeps rolling back and staying).

In the past (years ago), I used msizap.exe that comes with the Windows SDK. But it doesn't seem to come with it anymore. I installed it and can't find it. My only guess is that it's no longer relevant in Windows 10.

Anyway, is there a best way to forcibly remove the product so that Windows no longer thinks it's installed?

Comment: I revamped the answer a bit, please have another look if you have read it already.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***msizap.exe***: You are correct, **`msizap.exe`** has been deprecated long ago.

---

***Broken Uninstall Workarounds***: This problem is very common. You can find [**a list of approaches for these kind of uninstall problems here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876981/129130).

- The easiest and fastest is probably to just use the [Microsoft FixIt tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) to remove the package. This basically "unregisters it" by the looks of it, and is similar to **`msizap.exe`** in that regard.
- If this is just a single machine you can hack the cached installation database using Orca ([how to find cached msi path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58775693/129130), [powershell version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47208200/129130), [using Windows Explorer - point 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41735092/129130)) - if it involves many machines you should make a patch. Please see details in link above.

***Virtual Machines***: It is obvious, but just to mention that you should check setups on virtual machines so you can just revert the virtual machine when you encounter "development and QA bugs" like these.

***Custom Action Flag***: You can also add a condition to each custom action so that you can disable the whole custom action from running by a custom command line sent to **`msiexec.exe`**.

If your flag is a property **`RUNCA="1"`**, then you can disable it by setting this flag property to **`0`** via the command line - this is sort of a little inoculation for the package's uninstall feature breaking - you can disable custom actions from running at all during install / uninstall - it might even be useful for your tech-support guys and real-world installations:

```
msiexec.exe /x {PRODUCT-CODE} RUNCA=0
```