# How to find 'product_id' for the 'win_package' Ansible module?

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, ansible-facts, beyondcompare

I'm tried to automate installation of a range of programs, including 7-zip, Adobe Reader, Beyond Compare, etc, for about 30 different programs.

For the first 2, I was able to find something that worked for `product_id`. Adobe Reader required hunting through the registry, trying stuff, and eventually getting lucky.

For Beyond Compare, I'm stuck. Spent hours searching through the registry and trying different things. Whatever I try, the module re-install b/c it doesn't recognize the product id.

I've also tried finding some mysterious MSI file, as per various forums recommendations, but one doesn't seem to exist for Beyond Compare.

In addition, I've tried a LOT of Powershell commands to try to gather more detailed installation information, but still with no luck (`winget`, `Get-WmiObject`, etc).

What am I missing? Is there another way to get the `product_id` for installers with no MSI file, or post installation? Is making this module idempotent a lost cause?

```yaml
- name: Install Beyond Compare
  ansible.windows.win_package:
    path: C:\temp\BCompare-4.4.3.26655.exe
    product_id: ?
    arguments: /VERYSILENT /NORESTAR
```

For `product_id`, I've tried a range of things:

- `BCompare`
- `BeyondCompare`
- `Scooter Software`
- `Beyond Compare 4`
- `Beyond Compare 4.4.3`

**Research Links**

- [Where the MSI file is copied after the installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071860/where-the-msi-file-is-copied-after-the-installation)
- [`ansible.windows/blob/main/plugins/modules/win_package.ps1`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.windows/blob/main/plugins/modules/win_package.ps1)
- [Ansible Issue #19996: "*`win_package`: should not require `product_id` information*"](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19996)
- https://www.codetwo.com/kb/msi-from-exe/
- https://bobcares.com/blog/powershell-list-installed-software/

Answer (score 0):

Right after I post this, I FINALLY figured it out ... Gonna leave this in case it helps someone.

- 7-zip `product_id: 7-Zip`
- Acrobat Reader `product_id: '{AC76BA86-7AD7-1033-7B44-AC0F074E4100}'`
- Beyond Compare `product_id: BeyondCompare4_is1`

How I found Beyond Compare's `product_id`:

- Windows Key + `cmd`
- `regedit` > enter
- Drilled down into `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\BeyondCompare4_is1`
- Looked around for a subfolder that was probably right. The name of the folder worked.

Comment: In case it's helpful, Beyond Compare's EXE installer uses [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). An MSI installer for Beyond Compare 4 is available on the [Alternate Installers for Windows](https://www.scootersoftware.com/kb/dl4_winalternate) page.