# InstallShield - Custom Action is missing in software uninstall routine

Tags: c#, windows, custom-action, installshield-le

I'm facing a problem with InstallShield installer.

I'd created a installer with a wrong custom action called in "After System Changes" event which should alert a message to the user.

This action was made in JScript, but in one of the builds I removed the JScript file and forgot to remove the custom action call.

Because that, I have the software installed on my pc and now I can't to uninstall it.

When I try, I get the message:
"Error 1720. There is a problem with this windows installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel of package vendor. Custom action FeedbackInstallationComplete script error -2146823..."

[image]

I have no idea to solve this problem.

Does someone knows how to solve it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does the MSI-packages have the same productcode? Have you tried uninstalling using `msiexec /x "pathToNewMSIWithoutCustomAction.msi" /qb+` ?

Comment: @FrodeF., I have tried uninstalling using msiexec, but not using /qb+

I'm trying it now and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: The best approach is to use to install the new msi using `REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus` like @MichaelUrman has provided. That will replace the cached msi in `c:\windows\installer` with the new fixed msi. After doing this, you can uninstall it again (which would now be done using the fixed msi).

Answer (score 0):

Typically the correct approach here is to create a minor upgrade that resolves the problem (either removing the custom action, or supplying the file), [install it with REINSTALLMODE=vomus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916340/89999), then uninstall the corrected package.

This is, unfortunately, a little harder with the limited edition, but shouldn't be outright impossible.

Comment: Ok @Michael. Thanks for your response. I will try it in few minutes and will let you know the result.