# Cashed msi installer with bug

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I create installer with bug and I can't uninstall or upgrade product (process is rollback every time). I sent this installer to client with more then >1000 station. Typically Windows use old installer from cache. There is any tips or argument to use new installer during uninstall for upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [REINSTALLMODE=vomus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916340) to replace the cached MSI with a fixed one. Your replacement must be a small update or minor upgrade of the currently cached one.

Answer (score -2):

Download [Microsoft Fix it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed), this will allow you to remove things that are showing as installed but cannot be updated/removed.