# Specifying location of uninstall .msi in RemoveExistingProducts

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, installaware

I'm writing an installer using WiX 3.5 for the latest version of our software. The installer for previous versions was written using InstallAware 8. During install I want to remove the old versions but InstallAware does some strange stuff so the normal RemoveExistingProducts method doesn't work. Neither does msiexec /x {PRODUCTCODE}.

When RemoveExistingProducts runs it pops up a dialog asking for the location of the .msi file from the old install. I can find the location of it in the registry and if I enter that location in the dialog the uninstall works fine. However I'd like for the dialog to not show, is there some way I can tell RemoveExistingProducts where to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some rules of avoiding prompts for source are violated. See if [these recommendations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/12/02/499495.aspx) help.

Comment: Specifically it seems that the MsiSourceListAddSource function might help, if providing that location to the prompt does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to this answer, please also check this answer: "[different ways to uninstall an MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130)".

Check in to see if there is a custom uninstall string defined for your old setup:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\YOUR GUID HERE\UninstallString**

This is the most common location used by the **Add/Remove applet in Control Panel**. If you find the uninstall string here you can run the uninstall via a custom action before running your new install. A bit ugly, I would prefer to run the install process via a setup.exe.

Another location is:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products**

Here you will find packed GUIDs. Check under each GUID and then under "**InstallProperties**" for the **InstallSource**. This path is the search path where the installation engine will look for the MSI file it needs to uninstall the application.

Answer (score 0):

In the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVerison\Uninstall\<GUID_or_product_name>\WindowsInstaller` key is set to 1, then you need to look in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\<mangled_guid>\InstallProperties\InstallSource` to see where it thinks the .msi is cached. Basically, make sure you're looking at the right registry location when searching for InstallSource.