# Silent installation of a MSI package

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I have a MSI package that I need to install if the package is not already installed. Also I need to install it silently. The package prompts user for:

- Installation location (C:\Program Files\Foobar)
- Install type: minimal and full (minimal)

I need to override these two parameters using command line parameters or some other method. So how do I go about these two issues. I'll use VBScript for scripting.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You should be able to use the `/quiet` or `/qn` options with `msiexec` to perform a silent install.

MSI packages export public properties, which you can set with the `PROPERTY=value` syntax on the end of the `msiexec` parameters.

For example, this command installs a package with no UI and no reboot, with a log and two properties:

```
msiexec /i c:\path\to\package.msi /quiet /qn /norestart /log c:\path\to\install.log PROPERTY1=value1 PROPERTY2=value2
```

You can read the options for `msiexec` by just running it with no options from Start -> Run.

Comment: Is there a way to find a list of acceptable parameters (`PROPERTY1` and `PROPERTY2` in your example)?

Comment: Here is the predefined properties list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=VS.85).aspx

The installation folder property is different for each setup authoring tool. What did you use to create the MSI?

Comment: @Cosmin: MSI consists of runtime DLLs of a payment system (not created by me). I am looking at a tool called Ocra to dissect the MSI, it gave me a hint about a variable called "INSTALLLOCATION". I am checking.

Comment: Then INSTALLLOCATION is most likely the installer property associated with the main installation folder. Try setting it through msiexec command line.

Comment: @SalmanA - Ocra is a great tool. It should be able to dissect all the custom UI elements. If I remember correctly, all custom UI input elements in MSI packages have a variable attached to them which is exported, so you can access the value via the command line.

Comment: (i) I wasn't able to check whether the package was already installed so I used another trick (ii) I managed to explicitly specify the install location via the `INSTALLLOCATION` parameter.

Comment: Note: msiexec seemed to be pretty picky about specifying the FULL file path to the MSI package. Don't try any of this `.\mypackage.msi` business. Took me a little bit to figure that out.

Comment: The name of the MS product is actually Orca, not ocra.  Might be hard to google with the misspelling.  You might get a lot of Creole recipes... but not MSI builders.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 23):

The proper way to install an MSI silently is via the `msiexec.exe command line` as follows:

```
msiexec.exe /i c:\setup.msi /QN /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"
```

Quick explanation:

```
 /L*V "C:\Temp\msilog.log"= verbose logging
 /QN = run completely silently
 /i = run install sequence
```

There is a much more comprehensive answer here: **[Batch script to install MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229460/batch-script-to-install-msi/25230485#25230485)**. This answer provides details on the **msiexec.exe command line options** and a description of **how to find the "public properties"** that you can set on the command line at install time. These properties are generally different for each MSI.

---

- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)