# run .MSI Installer from C# coding

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.0

I have used the MySQL 5.6.12 in my project i want to install this MySQL setup from myproject deployment setup.exe. how to install the MySQL from myproject setup installer silently .i also want to set the myproject path to the MySQL installer means MySQL install in myproject path 
(C:\ProgramFIles\glob\myproject\MySQL).

Thanks

Comment: [Well install it silently, then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package). *i also want to set the myproject path to the MySQL installer means MySQL install in myproject path* What if the user already has MySQL installed?

Comment: when installing mysql silently that time mysql install in default path like C:\programfile\mysql\ but i want to install the mysql in my project path not in mysql default path

Comment: What if it's already installed at *C:\programfile\mysql* And the user has their installation just the way they want it. Do you want to uninstall MySQL and re-install it to *C:\Program Files\glob\myproject\MySQL*?

Comment: actually MySQL install with myproject setup, nothing is install already in windows.install MySQL from myproject windows setup