# Installing EXE without User Interaction

Tags: command-prompt, silent-installer, windows-server-2012-r2

Is there any scripting language available for creating Silent Installation (without giving input and clicking next, agree and finish)...? I want to do unattended installation of agent.exe application in windows server, which scripting would be best..?

```
       agent.exe /S /qn
```

2) Also am having msi for same like agent.msi, when i tried

```
   msiexec /qn /l* agent.txt /i agent.msi SSL_CERT_FILE=file-path
```

nothing happened,
May  i know script correct script to install EXE files without User Interaction ? i Dont want tool like Autoit, NSIS, etc only by command prompt i want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with MSI, you may want to take a look at the answer to this question: [Silent installation of a MSI package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package)

Can I suggest you try using IExpress? This program is installed in the SYSTEM32 folder of most Windows installations, and is designed for silent installations. Try pressing Win+R, then enter `iexpress`, and click Ok.

You may want to see the Wikipedia page for more information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IExpress

Comment: Mainly, want to install exe file, without UI, by suppying parameters, is there solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload / link the installer file somewhere. Without the real installer it is blind guessing what the correct parameter for this package is.

There are tons of different [installer types](https://silent-install.net/installer/start) around. Mostly you can run the installer with the paramter "/?" to see the supported parameters. If you have both exe and msi file in the same structure it is sometimes safer to use the exe file.