# Installing all .msi files within a folder

Tags: python, powershell, windows-installer

I'm trying to write a powershell script that I am kicking off from a python script that will allow me to go through and install each .msi file that is contained within a certain folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
$msiFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "***PATH TO FOLDER***" -Recurse -Include *.msi

foreach($file in $msiFiles)
{

    Write-Host "$file is being installed"
    Start-Process "msiexec.exe" -arg "/I $file /qb ADDLOCAL=ALL ALLUSERS=TRUE" -Wait
    Write-Host "$file is finished being installed"


}
```

I want to install these msi's in silent mode so I don't see or need ant GUI interaction. When it goes to install the msi's I get a pop up from the installer with all the possible commands to use to install stuff, but it doesn't actually install it.

What is the proper command to install these in silent mode?

Comment: Do this `Write-Host "/I $file /qb ADDLOCAL=ALL ALLUSERS=TRUE"` In your code right before the Start-Process line. Please put one sample of the output from that in your question.

Comment: Have you tried searching for it? Not very hard to find i think. Have a look at this answer from Polynomial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package

Comment: @Theo Yes I have tried using the steps in that link already but am still getting the same pop up I have described above

Comment: Note that [ALLUSERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/allusers) should be set to 0 or 1 (or 2 with MSIINSTALLPERUSER), not TRUE. Also ADDLOCAL=ALL may or may not be good, depending on the features within a given .msi file. (Neither of these are syntactically invalid, though, so aren't causing the problem you're asking about.)

Comment: Not an answer as such, but I just want to inform you of this: [**The Windows Installer PowerShell Module**](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi) on github.com - it provides **MSI cmdlets** (scroll down for description, use **releases tab for download** or read instructions). I haven't really tested it much, but it is from [Heath Stewart](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/) - Microsoft Senior Software Engineer (github).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, **if invoking `msiexec` does nothing but show a dialog describing the command-line syntax, the implication is that there's a *syntax problem*.**

The **likely source** of the syntax error is that the `"..."` string you're using as the `-arg` argument (full name: `-Args` or `-ArgumentList`) has `$file` embedded in it *without embedded quoting*:

That is, if **the value of `$file` has embedded *spaces***, for instance (e.g., `C:\Msi Installers\foo.msi`), the resulting `msiexec` command will be syntactically invalid, because the space-separated tokens of the path are *each* considered an argument.

[Bill_Stewart's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450691/45375) shows you how to **use *embedded quoting* around `$file`** to solve this problem, by enclosing it in `` `" `` (`` ` `` is PowerShell's escape character).

If you were to stick with passing the arguments as a *single* string, you would use:

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Args "/I `"$file`" /qb ADDLOCAL=ALL ALLUSERS=TRUE" -Wait
```

Arguably, however, **it's cleaner** not to pass a *single*, command-line-like string as the *only* argument, but to instead **pass the arguments as *elements of an array***, which is indeed what `-ArgumentList` / `-Args` was designed to accept (its parameter type is `[string[]]`):

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Args /I, `"$file`", /qb, ADDLOCAL=ALL, ALLUSERS=TRUE -Wait
```

Note how **`$file` is *still* passed with embedded quoting**, which is unfortunately **required due to [a bug in `Start-Process`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576)** (as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core v7.1); it looks like this bug will *not* get fixed, however, but the linked GitHub report suggests introducing a new
`-ArgumentArray` parameter with the correct behavior.

---

You may alternatively **build up the array of arguments in *advance***; note how this is done in *expression* mode (with syntax more like regular programming languages), so the array elements *all* require quoting; also note how I'm using *single* quotes to define *literal* arguments:

```
# Create the array of arguments to pass to msiexec
$msiArgs = 
  '/I',
  "`"$file`"",      #`# !! enclosing in `"...`" is needed due to the bug mentioned above
  '/qb',
  '/ADDLOCAL=ALL',
  'ALLUSERS=TRUE'

Start-Process msiexec.exe -Args $msiArgs -Wait
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
$msiFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "***PATH TO FOLDER***" -Recurse -Include *.msi

foreach ( $file in $msiFiles ) {
  $fullPath = $file.FullName
  Write-Host "'$fullPath' is being installed"
  Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/I `"$fullPath`"","/qb","ADDLOCAL=ALL","ALLUSERS=TRUE" -Wait
  Write-Host "$fullPath is finished being installed"
}
```