# Install msi and exe silent from network folder

Tags: powershell, installation, windows-installer, exe, silent

I am trying to have a script that will install exe and msi files in silent mode, but it's opening the installers instead of running silently.

```sh
#network drive path
$nwDrivePath = "\\server\folder\"                                                  #"

#check if path is valid
if (test-path $nwDrivePath){
    Set-Location $nwDrivePath
}
else{
    #if path is not valid abort
    Write-Output "No path found for $nwDrivePath"
    Write-Output "Aborting script"
    break script
}

#install .exe files
    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem $nwDrivePath -Filter *.exe | ForEach {
    Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList "/s"
    }

#install .msi files
    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem $nwDrivePath -Filter *.msi | ForEach {
    Start-Process $_.Fullname -ArgumentList "/qn"
    }
```

Comment: It's not working how? Any errors?

Comment: No error, just opens a installer, not silent.

Comment: The correct syntax to silently install an msi package is `msiexec.exe /i ...\msi-file.msi /qn`. You may read more about here: [msiexec Install Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec)

Comment: Thank you @Olaf can you help me put this in to this code?

Comment: If your .exe doesn't support silent installation then there is no option. But you can always do a silent installation using .msi files.

Comment: @AlexIvanov This might get you started: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/51448642/9196560](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51448642/9196560)