# MSIEXEC - Argumentlist with Variable

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I am trying to start an installation via msiexec.
The following parameters are available and if I use this on that way, the installation will be correct.
This is the example from the vendor:

`msiexec.exe /i ApexOne.msi MyServer="win2016-x64:8080|4343" MyDomain="Workgroup\Subdomain" /Lv+ "c:\temp\MSI.log"`

This is my code:

`Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList @('/i ".\agent.msi" MyServer="servername:8080|4344" MyDomain="999-Test"') -wait`

But for automation I have to use the variable $domain to generate the correct domain.
I tried different codes, but nothing helped:

This is the code for my variable $domain
`$domain='999-Test'`

Example:
`Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList @('/i ".\agent.msi" MyServer="servername:8080|4344" MyDomain=**"$domain"'**) -wait`

I tried that also, but I don't know how to fix this failure.
I think the interpration of the variable is false, but I can not fix it.

`-ArgumentList @('/i ".\agent.msi"','MyServer="servername:8080|4344"','MyDomain='$domain'')`

Maybe someone can help me to fix this error?

Comment: Single quotes treat the string as a literal string without doing interpolation (variable and expression substitution). You'll need to replace the outer ```'``` with ```"``` - so ```"MyDomain='$domain'"```. Note that you'd also need to escape any double-quotes *inside* your string with a backtick if there were any (e.g. ```"MyDomain=`"$domain`""```).

Comment: I used this one, but it does not work: ```@('/i ".\agent.msi" MyServer="servername:8080|4344" MyDomain=`"$domain`"') -wait```

Comment: With this one the install does not begin, there are missing the terminator ```'```. I: So I tried this one: ``Start-Process -FilePath "$env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe" -ArgumentList @('/i ".\agent_vorlage.msi" MyServer="av01.badencloud.de:8080|4344" "MyDomain=`"$domain`""') -wait```

Comment: You're mixing and mis-matching single and double quotes a little bit - that won't work. Try ```-ArgumentList @("/i `".\agent_vorlage.msi`" MyServer=`"av01.badencloud.de:8080|4344`" MyDomain=`"$domain`"")```. The whole string is surrounded by double-quotes ```"``` and the quotes *inside* are escaped with ```backtick double-quote``` - i.e. `"

Comment: Just skim reading today, [maybe have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460517/129130).

Answer (score 1):

The msiexec.exe program seems to have some peculiarities in its command-line parser. I recommend an approach like the following:

```
$msiFileName = ".\agent.msi"
$myServer = "servername:8080|4344"
$myDomain = "999-Test"
$argumentList = @(
  '/i'
  '"{0}"' -f $msiFileName
  'MyServer="{0}"' -f $myServer
  'MyDomain="{0}"' -f $myDomain
)
$startArgs = @{
  "FilePath" = "msiexec.exe"
  "ArgumentList" = $argumentList
  "Wait" = $true
}
Start-Process @startArgs
```

This example creates an array of string arguments for the `-ArgumentList` parameter using single quotes (`'`) and string formatting (`-f`). In the above example, each element in the `$argumentList` array is a separate string and contains the following elements:

```
/i
".\agent.msi"
MyServer="servername:8080|4344"
MyDomain="999-Test"
```

(Note that in the content of the array we are preserving the `"` characters.)

Next, we create a hashtable for the `Start-Process` cmdlet and call it using the `@` operator. (Creating a hashtable for a cmdlet's parameters is known as *[splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.1)* and is a convenient way to build a large number of parameters for a cmdlet in a more readable and maintainable way.)

Answer (score 1):

- **Due to a long-standing bug in [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process), it is actually preferable to always pass all arguments for the target process *encoded in a single string* passed to `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`)**, rather than *individually*, as elements of an *array* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375).
- Doing so requires two things:

  - To incorporate variable values, you must use an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), i.e. **a *double*-quoted string, `"..."`**.
  - **Any *embedded* quoting *inside* this overall `"..."` string *must* itself use *double*-quoting only**, as CLIs on Windows generally only understand `"` (double quotes) and not also `'` (single quotes) to have *syntactic* function. To embed `"` characters in a `"..."` string, **escape them as `` `" ``** (or as `""`; inside a `'...'` string, you needn't escape them at all).

While this is somewhat cumbersome, it **does have the *advantage* of allowing you to directly control the exact command line that the target process will see** - and that enables you satisfy `msiexec`'s picky syntax requirements where `PROP="value with spaces"` must be passed exactly with this value-only double-quoting (whereas PowerShell - justifiably - turns this argument into `"PROP=value with spaces"` behind the scenes, when it - of necessity - *re-quotes* arguments to synthesize the actual command line to use).

Therefore, use the following (using *positional* argument binding to `-FilePath` and `-ArgumentList`, respectively):

```sh
Start-Process -Wait $env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe "/i .\agent.msi MyServer=`"servername:8080|4344`" MyDomain=`"999-Test`""
```

<sup>Note: Strictly speaking, you do not need the embedded `` `"...`" `` quoting in your case, given that your property values have no *embedded spaces*.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for these Powershell hints on msiexec.exe issues. I added a couple of your answers to my [experimental deployment information grid](https://installdude.com/jumpgate.php) - so I can find them easily.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @SteinÅsmul - looks like a handy collection of information.

Comment: It is still quite experimental, but it helps quite a bit now and then - especially when you are on a machine without all your other tools available.