# WiX: WIX Logs show two INSTALL actions. What is the first one?

Tags: wix, wix3.8, wix3.10, wix3.11, wix3.9

I am analyzing the WiX logs (/Lv) during the installation process very carefully. What i realized, that during the install process two *INSTALL* actions will be started. The second one during the first is still processing. What is the first Install Action doing? Can i hook a *CustomAction* into the first Install step? Because every *CustomAction* i define with Before="a_state" will be executed in the second INSTALL run.
Inside of the .wixobj i dont see any hint for the first INSTALL run and when i analyze the source code of WiX i dont find any hint nether.

Comment: Is that just both the GUI-sequence and the install-sequence running I wonder? [You can try to install silently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46780834/129130) and verify that there should be only one INSTALL action in the log afterwards? (since the UI sequence is skipped for silent installations).

Comment: There are also other details to understand such as the difference between immediate and deferred mode custom actions. Immediate mode custom actions may run twice during the installation sequence due to technicalities of Windows Installer. This is somewhat complicated, I can try to summarize if you want.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Would be nice. Especially the Immediate runs twice part.