# Install msi file using powershell script

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I am new in power shell. i need to install file using powershell. My msi file location is C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.

I have tried with the powershell script

```
Start-Process C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi
msiexec /i "C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi" /qn+
```

When i executing the above script gets installation windows. ie; click to next to install(Displayed window) the above msi file(i need to remove this window). but actually i want, installation should works automatically when executing powershell script.

So i need to execute installation using powershell script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package/8560308

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
$arguments = "/i `"C:\Amazon\AWSCLIV2.msi`" /quiet"
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait
```

Comment: I have tried the above script. but installation not happened.