MySQL Community Command Line Install Package options
I am really hoping someone can help me get over this hurdle. I am trying to do a command line install of MySQL Community 5.6.19. I've utilized the --help command to see the list of commands, the first needed being '/package <Product.msi>' or '/a <Product.msi>'. However, for the life of me I can't figure out what exactly is needed there. I even tried looking at the log file hoping something in there would clue me into the parameter I need, but no luck so far.
My goal is to perform a Full Install, installing any requirements, skipping check for updates & Start MySQL Workbench, while providing a default password. What I currently have below creates a log but still displays the UI prompting the user to perform all the configuration.
mysql-installer-community-5.6.19.0.msi /norestart /log MySQL_Install.log


I had a similar issue on Linux, trying to automate installation of the MySQL yum package. They don't document the names of the install properties, which the installer needs to prompt you to get. I had to read the code of the installer builder. Fortunately it's open source. But I have no idea about their Windows installer (I don't use Windows).

The answer on this post shows how to run an MSI installer in "quiet mode" to avoid the UI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560166/silent-installation-of-a-msi-package But you would still need to know the properties specific to that installer.

Why are you installing MySQL 5.6.19? That's an unsupported version from 2014. It's not even the last 5.6.x release.

Reviving a prior application and that was the version supported. Hoping to update in the future, but for now we need to stay with that.

@Cyber: But why do you need "MySQL Workbench" for this old version? just a mysqldump should do, to allow you to import this into a newer version.... (I do not think Workbench is in the old MSI ?)

Please note that the option (after --help) are the options needed for: "Windows ® Installer. V 5.0.22621.1".    Why do you need a silent install? (which can be done using /qn, for "No UI")

I do not know the full extent of the use of MySQL tools for this program, as I am still onboarding. The installation document that we are utilizing specifies to perform a FULL install, so in order to replicate what was done in the past I am trying to mirror that configuration in the new environment.
As I mentioned we are not looking to migrate at this time. As of now I have a requirement to utilize 5.6.19.

With regards to the options. I am aware of the help command and was able to utilize that to get a list of options. However, it is unclear how to utilize the /a or /package option, which is why I reached out here. I have been unable to get an install successful using that option.

msiexec /i mysql-installer-community-5.6.19.0.msi is the same as mysql-installer-community-5.6.19.0.msi
