# Is source-code for Deployment Tools Foundation available?

Tags: wix

I have been trying to find source-code for *Deployment Tools Foundation* or rather for `Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.dll` to understand better how the `IUnpackStreamContext` interface works.

I did find a blogpost from [Rob Mensching](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23852/rob-mensching) saying that Deployment Tools Foundation is [now a part of WiX](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/5/16/Deployment-Tools-Foundation-joins-the-WiX-toolset).  If I understand right the source-code would be available for browsing somewhere, somehow.

Anyone know if/where the source is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DTF is part of WiX and its source code is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/DTF).

Comment: Gah! I had checked out the code locally. I just failed to look at the right path /src/DTF/Libraries.
Thanks!