# Can't uninstall program from command line (wix msi)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I've created MSI package using WiX toolset, when I'm trying to uninstall it using command line:

```
msiexec /x f987d323-303f-49a0-92e8-d1ab41589719
```

msiexec shows me the error:

"This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

**But I can remove it from "Add or Remove Programs" without any problems**. I've double checked that msi md5 checksum is correct and placed msi on local disk, but seems this is not connected.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried including the curly braces around the GUID?

```
msiexec /x {f987d323-303f-49a0-92e8-d1ab41589719}
```

Comment: For reference, more details on msi uninstall here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933

Answer (score 0):

**Kenuat**: msiexec.exe has just about the clumsiest command line interface I have ever seen. Even simple operations are complex syntactically.

To deal with the complicated **msiexec.exe command line interface**, I use a free tool from **Altiris** to help me build all msiexec.exe command lines, barring the most basic ones - and I have used msiexec.exe daily for years: http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe (highly recommended).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]