# How to get a program's GUID in .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, guid, uninstallation, windows-installer

I want to uninstall a program using a C# code. I can simply do it by using `msiexec.exe` but in order to use it, I need to have the GUID of the program I want to uninstall. If the only thing I've got of this program is it's name then how can I find it's GUID?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that reliably, you would need more information - applications can have the same 'name'.

Use an installer/uninstaller that is the package of the program.