# Need Uninstall command for MSI Package in bundle bootstrapper

Tags: wix, uninstallation, windows-installer

I have chain package and install commands in bundle bootstrapper, this bundle bootstrapper has .net sqlserver, and custom software (msi package) also. The install process called from install button click (windows application), The install process is working fine, and i need to write the uninstall command for the custom software (msi package) in bundle bootstrapper. please help, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to uninstall and MSI that's in the bundle or one that's installed separately?

Comment: i installed the msi from that bundle, and I am trying to uninstall the msi from the same bundle.. , i don't know the uninstall command. please help..

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall a bundle, find the bootstrapper's entry under "Programs and Features" (ARP) and uninstall it from there. (If you want to know the command, search for the displayed text in the registry and look at the associated UninstallString value).

Uninstalling the bundle will uninstall the non-permanent packages that aren't still used by other bundles.

---

`MsiPackages` don't have install or uninstall command attributes because the bootstrapper engine ("burn") knows how to invoke Windows Installer with appropriate arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Please see similar questions answered in older threads:

- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)
- Silent Install of MSI: https://serverfault.com/questions/30068/silent-install-of-msi/67001#67001

These are direct links to specific answers in the threads, please read the whole thread for each one - just so I don't lead you in the wrong direction.

**My recommendation**: get hold of the **Wise Command Line builder tool** described in the **second thread** to get the command line easily generated.