# Creating a MSI package with batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-installer

we have a requirement  to uninstall an application from windows machine.I have created a batch file to with uninstall commands,converted the batch file into a exe and by using MSI package installer created a package.
When i tried to install this other machine this was  found as virus/Spyware.

Is this because of bat file in the exe?

Comment: Type `iexpress` in Start Run andsee if that works.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Chris is right, this needs more explanation. The requirement seems to be uninstalling an application, so the part about creating an MSI package to achieve this is confusing. It's also not clear if the install or running the app afterwards is being flagged as virus.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.My requirement is create a msi package including the batch file.Once package is installed in client machine and clicking on the msi application batch file should should execute the command to uninstall the applications.

Comment: My question is can i create a MSI package with batch file included?If yes how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume this is due to the tool you used to create the EXE file with. Other than that you can take a look at [various ways to uninstall MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130).

I don't know what kind of network you are on, but normally an uninstall like this is best done via a deployment tool, WMI, PowerShell or similar. There are many ways.