# How do I programmatically uninstall a cached Wix Burn program

Tags: wix

I have created a Wix Burn app that I am installing two MSI's with.  Works great.

1. The MSI files install properly
2. The Wix Burn app registers with ARP.
3. The MSI files do not register with ARP
4. I can do Major Upgrades
5. I can install and uninstall manually with a local copy of the Wix Burn app
6. I can programmatically execute the Wix Burn app to uninstall (using /x)

The Problem:

I know two way to uninstall using a Wix Burn app:

1. Click on the Uninstall button in ARP (requires user involvement)
2. Launch a copy of the Wix Burn app that installed the product

I see in the Wix Burn log that Windows caches my Wix Burn app install in much the same way that MSIEXEC will cache MSI files. Is there a way to programmatically ask Windows or MSI to use the cached version of the Wix Burn app to do the uninstall?

A Possibility:

Presumably I could use MsiGetProductInfo() to get a path to the cached Wix Burn app.  To do that, however, I need my app's Product Code.  However, Product Codes are not attributes of  elements in Wix so I am not seeing how to get a Product Code for a Burn package.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this by iterating through the `Uninstall` registry entries.  The process is:

1. Open `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.
2. Iterate through the sub-keys searching for an entry where the `Publisher` and `DisplayName` matches your product.
3. If you find an entry, read the value of `QuietUninstallString` and run that as a command.  For a WIX burn installer this is typically in the form `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{GUID}\SetupProgram.exe /uninstall /quiet`.

If you are using a 64 bit operating system you will also need to search `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

Comment: I think this should work. Just a couple of further links:  [Uninstall MSI file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933) and [find guid of installed MSI file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup).