wix not removing msi file from control panel
I am using wix installer to install an msi file (Please see the code at the bottom). Doing so, its able to install fine. I can se the folder under,

C:\Program Files\PharmSpec

But not I want to uninstall this file when they rerun the installer or upgrade to a newer version of the installer. I have the following piece of code that's doing that. I can see the PharmSpec folder deleted from C:\Program Files and I can see the desktop shortcut icon being deleted. But problem is, I can't get it to go from the Control Panel. Please help.
public static class UninstallPrevVersion
    {
        private const string UNINSTALL_COMMAND = "/quiet /x  {0} ALLUSERS=1 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 MSIFASTINSTALL=7 SERIALNUMBER=X DBSELECTED=1 PHARMSPECSELECTED=1 REBOOT=ReallySuppress IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL REMOVE=ALL;";
        public static void UninstallOldPharm( WixBootstrapper bootstrapper, string msiProductCode)
        {
            bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "starting uninstall old Pharmspec version for upgrade");
            string command = string.Format(UNINSTALL_COMMAND, msiProductCode, bootstrapper.Engine.StringVariables["PreviousSerial"]);
            bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, command);
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec", command);
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo = info;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.Start();
            string outputD = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            if (proc.WaitForExit(60000))
            {
                bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, outputD);
            }
            else
            {
                bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "Process timeout in UninstallOldPharm");
            }
            bootstrapper.Engine.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "uninstalled old PharmSpec version for upgrade");
        }
    }

DEBUGGING:
On the command prompt, I am running the above UNINSTALL_COMMAND as follows,
msiexec /quiet /x {959C7390-F8FE-4E7C-BF34-27357313F135} ALLUSERS=1 ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1 MSIFASTINSTALL=7 SERIALNUMBER=X DBSELECTED=1 PHARMSPECSELECTED=1 REBOOT=ReallySuppress IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL REMOVE=ALL; 

I am getting the number {959C7390-F8FE-4E7C-BF34-27357313F135} from regedit

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{959C7390-F8FE-4E7C-BF34-27357313F135}

When I run this command, I can see the PharmSpec folder deleted from C:\Program Files and the desktop icon being removed too. But under Control Panel and the registry in the above path, I still see them. How can I remove the PharmSpec from the ControlPanel. When I reinstall a newer version of the installer, I can see 2 entries in the Control Panel with 2 different versions.

Here is how the PharmSpec.msi package is being installed,
<PackageGroup Id="PharmSpecMsi">
            <MsiPackage Id="PharmSpecInstaller"
                              SourceFile="$(var.ReleaseFolder)\!(loc.CULTURE)\PharmSpec.msi"
                              DisplayInternalUI="yes"
                              ForcePerMachine="yes"
                              Visible="no"
                InstallCondition="1">
                <MsiProperty Name="UPGRADEPHARM" Value="[MAINUPGRADE]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="ADD_USER_ADMIN" Value="[UserAdmin]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="ADD_USER_CALTECH" Value="[TechUser]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="CUSTOMER" Value="[Customer]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="SERIALNUMBER" Value="[CdKey]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="REGSEVERITY" Value="[Severity]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="DBSERVERNAME" Value="[DBServerName]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="DBDSN" Value="[Dbdsn]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="DBUID" Value="[Dbuid]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="DBPWD" Value="[Dbpwd]"/>
                
                <MsiProperty Name="REGDATE" Value="[RegDate]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="REGLANG" Value="[RegLang]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="REGSEP" Value="[RegSep]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="REGTIME" Value="[RegTime]"/>
                
                <MsiProperty Name="DBSELECTED" Value="[INSTALLSQL]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="NOTCURRENTDB" Value="[Sql2022InstanceFound]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="PHARMSPECSELECTED" Value="[INSTALLPHARM]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="OLDDBDATAPATH" Value="[OLDDBDATAPATH]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[InstallDir]"/>
                <MsiProperty Name="TARGETDIR" Value="[TargetDir]"/>

            </MsiPackage>
        </PackageGroup>


I finally figured out the solution. Here is what I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613910/how-do-i-programmatically-uninstall-a-cached-wix-burn-program
When I deleted the registry key manually under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, its removing from the control panel. is there a way, how do I get the appropriate registry key to delete.
