Trying to delete a registry subkey is giving "System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
I want to delete an entire child element from the registry tree where the key name value of Publisher is HIAC. I am running VisualStudio as an administrator. In my code when I say

key.DeleteSubKeyTree(childKey);

It throws an exception saying,

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Cannot write to the registry
key.'

Please help. This is what I am trying.
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall");
            foreach (var childKey in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                RegistryKey productKey = key.OpenSubKey(childKey);
                if (productKey != null)
                {
                    var keyValues = productKey.GetValueNames();
                    if (keyValues.Any(x => x.Equals("Publisher", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                    {
                        var value = productKey.GetValue("Publisher").ToString();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && value.Equals("HIAC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            key.DeleteSubKeyTree(childKey);
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

To test this, I created a Key within the path as shown in the screenshot. I want to delete this ATESTKey


Are you running in an elevated context?

Yes I am running VisualStudio as an admin

The Uninstall subkey is typically only used by installers/uninstallers. You'll most likely need to perform the operation as administrator - see the first part of this post. For a solution to the other issues, use the answer in this post as a guide.

I want to make this work for wix installer project. Thank you so much. I want to use it for this scenario https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79311136/wix-not-removing-msi-file-from-control-panel

It's not clear what version of WIX Toolset you're using. In v3, you'd use Fragment => ComponentGroup => Component => RegistryValue to create a subkey under Software to store your information. There shouldn't be a need to do anything with the Uninstall subfolder.

This is what worked, adding an attribute Writable:True to the OpenSubKey method as in this post here.
Here is the full code. Make sure to open VisualStudio as an admin.
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string keyPath = @"Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyPath, writable: true);
            foreach (var childKey in key.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                RegistryKey productKey = key.OpenSubKey(childKey);
                if (productKey != null)
                {
                    var keyValues = productKey.GetValueNames();
                    if (keyValues.Any(x => x.Equals("Publisher", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                    {
                        var value = productKey.GetValue("Publisher").ToString();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && value.Equals("HIAC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            key.DeleteSubKeyTree(childKey);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }


I highly recommend that you use the code in the post that I previously mentioned rather than specifying Wow6432Node. The code in the referenced post uses RegistryView. It also shows to use the constructor that opens the subkey in write mode.

Sure I will use the code in the post.

I did. Likewise can you not downvote my question. I understand you were not the one.

Wasn't me, but as a gesture of goodwill I'll give it an upvote to cancel out the downvote.
