# Trouble uninstalling program through normal means

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstallation

Once I access add or remove programs I was not able to locate my desired program to uninstall.  After this, I decided to to try and use IObit uninstaller to try and find it, but that couldn't either.  The program can still be found in my Program File directory and it acknowledges that I have it installed when I try to reinstall it.  A system restore was no help either.  Netbeans is the program.

Comment: Wrong site. You''re looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information can be found in the [help]. Good luck.

Comment: my bad.  Appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: [**Sections 4 or 11 here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1055933/129130) may be of help: It depends if it is a Windows Installer or not.

Comment: Please see answer below, and maybe comment on any extra steps necessary if it works. **As long as it is a developer tool it is relevant for developers I'd say** - add to the community knowledge of "how to avoid wasting time".

Answer (score 0):

The below is a custom installer / uninstaller approach for NetBeans - a package in a proprietary format (non-MSI). For normal uninstall of Windows Installer packages see this "reference answer" instead: [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933).

---

**I see NetBeans in the Add / Remove applet just fine** - just right-click and select "Uninstall".

---

I suppose the entry could be missing on your system. If this is the case you can try this:

- Go to the NetBeans installation folder and double click `Uninstall.exe`.
- On my system the installation path is: `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2`.
- You should get an uninstall dialog with a couple of options, set options as appropriate and click `Uninstall`.

I'll throw in the uninstall dialog so people can see the options - I suppose it could be helpful for someone at some point. **I didn't run the actual uninstall, please update this answer with any extra steps necessary** once you do run it:

[image: NetBeans Uninstall]