# Python Silent installation - Python does not appear in Control Panel although ALLUSERS=1 is used

Tags: python, python-2.7, powershell, windows-installer, silent-installer

I am using python installation: python-2.7.13.amd64.msi
I know it is old but we really must use 2.7 because of specific program.

I try to install that package from DevOps platform, I try to set for Pyhton to be for ALL USERS

```
$TMP_INSTALLATION="C:\Octopus\Applications\Temp"
$FOLDER="C:\Octopus\Applications"
$arguments_python = @(
"/quiet",
"ALLUSERS=1",
"/l* $TMP_INSTALLATION\PythonInstallLog.txt"
)
Write-Host("========== Python Installation Install ==========")
Start-Process -FilePath "$FOLDER\python-2.7.13.amd64.msi" -ArgumentList $arguments_python -Wait
Write-Host("========== Python Installation Complete ==========")
```

Folder C:\Python27 is created, registry for Python is created but no program is presented in **Control Panel.**
I thought that by adding argument ALLUSERS=1 will resolve the issue but nothing. Maybe I am missing some syntax?

From docs:
"ALLUSERS=1 causes an installation for all users. By default, the non-interactive installation install the package just for the current user, and the interactive installation offers a dialog which defaults to "all users" if the user is sufficiently privileged."
Python is recognizable from other programs because of this and I cannot properly uninstall the python because it does not exist in Control Panel.

Please help me, I am trying to do the silent installation from PowerShell from specific platform but cannot install it successfully. If I run it from the server side it can be installed properly.

Thanks

Comment: Is your question how do uninstall Python after a silent install? If so, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec) might help you.

Comment: Hi. No it is not.
My question is why I cannot install it so it can be presented in Control Panel although I am using "ALLUSERS=1". 
Also because of this then my pip is not recognized as command since Python is not installed properly for all users.

I need help in order to determine why I cannot install Pyhton properly so it is presented in Control Panel when I am isntalling it from external system using the PowerShell code.
Thank you in advance