# How to launch an MSI uninstaller with ShellExecute?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating an app that can uninstall, remove and rename applications.

I get a list of them from Registry functions. I can delete them from the Registry, or rename them, but I can't uninstall applications that have an MSI, like Python or MySQL, for example.

With `ShellExecute()`, I can uninstall apps that have an uninstall string like `"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\uninstall.exe"`. But if an application has an uninstall string like `MsiExec.exe /I{D5201299-C610-4861-BFB6-A85BCCC69046}` then nothing happens.

I can't understand what I should do.

I can launch an MSI just by calling `system()`, like `system("start MsiExec.exe /I{D5201299-C610-4861-BFB6-A85BCCC69046}")`, but it doesn't work with `uninstall.exe`.

Official MSDN didn't help me in any way to understand that problem.

So my question is: How can I uninstall an MSI app with `ShellExecute()`?

Here is my code:

```
wstring uninstall_string;
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", uninstal_string.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec)

Comment: Why `ShellExecute`? It has no useful means of indicating errors (hence the existence of `ShellExecuteEx`) and it ultimately just calls `CreateProcess` for this sort of task. Why not call `CreateProcess` directly and cut out the intermediary.

Comment: But how can i launch a cmd with parameters from createprocess?

Comment: If you read the documentation for CreateProcess that should be obvious. Did you?