# Why does the MSI installer reconfigure if I delete a file?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, resiliency, advertised-shortcut

I have created an MSI installer package in Visual Studio 2008. The problem is that after install, if I delete ANY of the installed files. This is not my intended behavior for my installer package. My File installation properties are:

PackageAs vsdpaDefault
Permanent False
ReadOnly False
Register vsdrfDoNotRegister
System False
Transitive False
Vital False

If this is trivial, please forgive me. I can't believe I have not been able to get Google to give up the answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***Windows Installer** is a **deployment technology**, its job is to install the specified files and registry settings and keep them in the specified install locations and to ensure they are the right versions - self-repair or resiliency is a mechanism to that end. Its operation conflicts with a developer's need to exchange files on the fly for debugging, development and testing.*

As a developer you may be interested in deploying your MSI and then deleting or replacing files on the fly to debug things. In these cases MSI can be a nuisance because it never stops doing its job and will reinstall the correct files. This is called "**self-repair**" and can be spectacularly annoying! :-).

There are a lot of ways to work around this, MSI is quite complex. ***Since the "self-repair" is normally invoked from an [`"advertised shortcut"`](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/advertised-shortcuts.html) the easiest way to avoid this MSI feature is to launch the EXE file directly from the file system and not via a shortcut***. This bypasses the MSI self repair mechanism for all but the most complex EXE files. You can also manually create a non-advertised shortcut on the desktop that will not trigger a self-repair (right click and hold executable and whilst holding down the right mouse button, drag-and-drop to desktop and release button over an empty spot and click "Create shortcut here").

For the record self-repair is triggered by "[self-repair entry points](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/initiating-self-repair-and-advertising-features-entry-point)" (this excellent, little article has disappeared for me - perhaps it is still there if you log in) for key-path validation. They include `advertised shortcuts`, `file extension associations`, `file MIME type association`, `COM verb activation` ([for example open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/fa-verbs)), `COM activation` (registry) and `direct call to Windows Installer` and maybe even a few other things.

> [**MSI Advertisement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/advertisement). In essence an advertised MSI installer is not
> installed, but registered on the system to be installed when invoked
> via "some mechanism" (the entry points above).

There is a lot more to **self-repair**, or **resiliency** which is its official name, please check [**this comprehensive article on self-repair problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263) to find ways to resolve your specific problem. It is a long article, but it should be worth the read if you have self-repair problems.

---

> ***UPDATE, October 2018***:

***Self-Repair In Detail***: More than anyone wants to know about self-repair:

1. [Self-repair - explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)
2. [Self-repair - finding real-world solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110)
3. [Self-repair - how to avoid it in your own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828724/how-do-i-avoid-triggering-msi-self-repair-with-my-wix-msi-package/45828725#45828725)

---

***Links***:

- Similar: [Visual Studio 2015 msi build initiates another installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569268/visual-studio-2015-msi-build-initiates-another-installation/52853946#52853946)
- [RestartManager causes worker role to restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152873/restartmanager-causes-worker-role-to-restart/55308732#55308732)
- [What is the use of Repair option in a msi installer and what does it really do (internally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613589/what-is-the-use-of-repair-option-in-a-msi-installer-and-what-does-it-really-do/49613785#49613785)
- [Disable MSI auto-repair on installed program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715332/disable-msi-auto-repair-on-installed-program/57717363#57717363)

Comment: Please note that there are a number of other ways to avoid triggering the repair. Most of these are not recommended, but using "non-advertised shortcuts" can be acceptable in some cases, for example when creating a version for the QA-team. With this kind of shortcut no self repair is triggered. For release versions I would enable advertised shortcuts since self repair is an important MSI feature.

Comment: **[Comprehensive explanation of self-repair](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6066263/129130)**

Answer (score 2):

It's by design, known as "resiliency": http://www.msifaq.com/a/1037.htm.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the party on this, but I have found that adding 'NeverOverwrite="yes"' to the Component definition of the file(s) that are intended to be modified after the install, stops the self-repair from undoing my changes.

This has all but solved my self-repair issue.  I added this to all configuration files and batch files within the MSI.

Comment: Yes, but don't do this to files you want updated like binaries or your setup will not update properly on upgrade - obviously. Better yet, make copies of settings files after installation and write to them leaving the original as an untouched "template". I am not sure if **`REINSTALLMODE=amus`** (force overwrite) would overwrite a key path set to "Never Overwrite". I remember testing it, but I don't remember what I found :-). That's what happens when you don't write it down. Thanks for sharing your tip!