# After installing Application it ask me admin credentials

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

I am a bit confused. I have a C # WPF application. This works as I wish when I run the EXE file.

Now I have set up an installer (Visual Studio Installer project). This installer installs the application as desired and creates a desktop shortcut.

If I start the application now via the desktop icon, then installer is executed again and it is asked for the admin access data. After entering the data, the application starts directly. And that happens every time I click on the desktop icon.

I use in the application project the costura.fody package to bind one executable.

Have someone ideas whats wrong?

I've read the desktop icon from Visual-Studio-Installer-Project check always the application state. I think this is why  the installer start every time I click the app icon on the desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Short Answer***: This is an MSI self-repair problem.
>
> 1. Work out what component triggers the self-repair. Details below.
> 2. Correct the situation by making changes to the setup eliminating the conflict situation.

---

***Self-Repair***: This is **`self-repair`**, or **`self-healing`** or **`"resiliency"`** depending on who you ask. I have a description here: **[Why does the MSI installer reconfigure if I delete a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981302/why-does-the-msi-installer-reconfigure-if-i-delete-a-file/5983973#5983973)** Towards the bottom there are three links. I would go for the one saying *"how to avoid in your own package"*.

***Understanding***: There is [a longer explanation of self-repair here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263). Section *"The Primary Causes of Self-Repair"* explains 3 main causes, yours being the  first one.

***Culprit***: You should check the event log for clues as to what file / component is triggering the self-repair:

- [Stefan Kruger's debugging procedure](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1037.htm)
- [My own version here (longer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6066263/129130) (section *"Finding the trigger or culprit for the self-repair"*).

Once you have worked out what component triggers the repair there are [a variety of fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110). But first maybe check the [list of common mistakes in your own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828724/how-do-i-avoid-triggering-msi-self-repair-with-my-wix-msi-package/45828725#45828725).

---

> ***Previous Answer***: Come to think of it there are several previous answers:
>
> - [Window's pop-up constantly appears when installed application is launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53730785/wix-toolkit-msi-installer-windows-pop-up-constantly-appears-when-installed/53734308#53734308) (seems better than the above)
> - [Visual Studio 2015 msi build initiates another installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569268/visual-studio-2015-msi-build-initiates-another-installation/52853946#52853946)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips.
I found missing registry keys in Event Viewer. By default, registry keys are set in a Visual Studio Installer project (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\[Manufacturer]`).

These are not needed by me and so I deleted the keys in the installer project. Now everything works as expected.