# windows program reinstalls itself for different logins on the computer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, registry, installshield-le

I created a Windows installer for a Client-Server program by using VS 2013 and InstallShield LE 2015.

I log in to a computer as Admin and run the installer. All works fine.

Then  I modify the registry for Local_Machine for some keys to define the database location etc. for the program (this was done by the installation initially as well, but due to certain issues discussed in [At each login the program tries to configure installation parameters in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190780/at-each-login-the-program-tries-to-configure-installation-parameters-in-the-hkey), I removed the registry modifying section from the installer).

I then run the program by double-clicking the shortcut placed by the installer on the desktop and test it. All works well.

Then I log off the computer.

Another user with admin rights logins and clicks on the shortcut, and the problem comes: the program starts to reinstall itself!

Then it fixes itself and runs fine.

But If the first user logins afterward, she experiences the same reinstall operation so does the first user afterward ad nauseam!

So, even though the installer does not create any registry items by itself, somehow, as soon as the program accesses the registry, or whatever it thinks broken, the Windows OS intervenes and tries to repair whatever needs fixing.

The InstallShield LE does not allow setting shortcuts to be "Advertised Shortcut", or

I delete the shortcut created by the installer and recreate it manually after the installation and yet experience the same problem. So the nature of the shortcut possibly is not the cause.

This problem only happens for multiple logins to the computer. If many people login by using the same credentials, it never happens.

So, what's wrong? I studied many StackOverflow answers to resolve this issue with no success. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Stein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129130/stein-%C3%85smul) gives a good set of instructions on how to diagnose problems with MSI programs in this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47190780/at-each-login-the-program-tries-to-configure-installation-parameters-in-the-hkey). When I followed his instructions, I was able to check which component of my MSI program has a problem.  It turns out, the serial bus controller library, MScomm32.ocx could not register under Win 10 properly. Once, I implemented the solution in this [link](https://github.com/davidanger/MSCOMM32), the above problem resolved and I could log in as two different users without initiating a reinstall process whenever the program icon was double-clicked to run.

Comment: That's great. Maybe check those files with virustotal.com to be sure (malware check - you probably already did). I wonder if you could run the application in **compatibility mode** as well? You can do that by right clicking the shortcut, select "**Properties**", "**Compatibility**" and then set options. I have never tried this. I guess that won't work for an ActiveX control like that. You might need registrationless COM to make it work. This would all be complicated. **Virtualization** could be yet another option - run it all in a Windows 7 / 8 virtual. Just listing whatever comes to mind.

Comment: Hello Stein. No, it did not work. Can we correspond privately? This is a project requiring your professional involvement as a deployment specialist.