# What happen when msiexec /i /quiet executed again with the same msi version?

Tags: windows-installer

I have a window service installed using **msiexec** with `/i /quiet` options. I want to know what **msiexec** do when I install it again using the same options and version of **msi**. Does it **repair** it or **force re-install**?

I know that `repair` or `re-install` should have the `/fa` option.

I tried removing a component/files and executed the command again, and it seems that it re-install or repair the application. I just want to make sure that this is what it does by default.

`msiexec.exe /i MySetup.msi INSTALLFOLDER="D:\My\Path\" /quiet /L*v install.log`

Comment: I think the **`i`** switch installs OR configures the MSI specified. As such it probably works like a [self-repair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983973/129130) checking for broken key-paths and installing components that need "fixing" if you run it a second time. That is the behavior I see here. You can do **`ADDLOCAL="FeatureName"`** with the **`i`** switch to install a missing feature locally, which matches a **Modify** or **Change** operation from the GUI.