# Disable MSI auto-repair on installed program

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, repair

I've seen tons of people post about this issue but have yet to find a solution. I have a program that every once and a while will have an issue where the windows installer tries to repair the program, but it doesn't actually do anything, it just hangs. I checked the Windows event log and the file it says is missing is not missing. Sometimes rebooting fixes it.

How can I disable the self repair completely on a program that's already installed without removing it completely from the registry? And how can I prevent future installations from having this problem? Thanks

Comment: Rule of Thumb: If you're having difficulty finding a programming language tag, your question is probably off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Intel***: Can you please summarize what kind of application this is? Does it
> have COM components? Does it feature GAC installation? Does it have
> services? Does it have a lot of registry information? Is it your own
> package or a third party package? Etc...

***Self-Repair***: This is a big issue, but a simple problem. The most concise explanation is probably this one: **[Why does the MSI installer reconfigure if I delete a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981302/why-does-the-msi-installer-reconfigure-if-i-delete-a-file/5983973#5983973)** (recommended).

> ***Essentially***: Windows Installer tries to maintain the files that were
> originally installed.

---

***External Causes***: Self-repair usually have 3 main causes: **`1)`** Badly designed MSI packages with design flaws, **`2)`** Interference from external causes ranging from malware, to admin scripts to anything on the system that changes "something" - really, and **`3)`** Windows Design changes that trigger unexpected errors in legacy packages.

> [**More here in section: "The Primary Causes of Self-Repair"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263).
> Given the intermittent nature of your problem it could be a security
> software problem?

---

***Blank GUIDs***: There is a method where you can install the files via components that has a blank GUID. Then they are simply installed and never checked again. This should eliminate self-repair problems, however it also means the file will never be updated.

***Other "Solutions"***: You must not try to disable the Windows Installer service or such things to resolve this problem, please try these pragmatic suggestions instead: [**Self-repair - finding real-world solutions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110) (section 5). You can for example use non-advertised shortcuts, sort out COM registration issues, etc... There is also this piece on the issue: [How do I avoid triggering MSI self-repair with my WiX / MSI package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828724/how-do-i-avoid-triggering-msi-self-repair-with-my-wix-msi-package/45828725#45828725) (recommended).

---

[Recent answer on a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607343/129130).

---

***Self-Repair In Detail***: More than anyone wants to know about self-repair. This is a section I created before, including it for its "glanceability":

1. [Self-repair - explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)
2. [Self-repair - finding real-world solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110) (third party packages)
3. [Self-repair - how to avoid it in your own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828724/how-do-i-avoid-triggering-msi-self-repair-with-my-wix-msi-package/45828725#45828725) (your own packages)

---

***Links***:

- Similar: [Visual Studio 2015 msi build initiates another installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569268/visual-studio-2015-msi-build-initiates-another-installation/52853946#52853946)
- [RestartManager causes worker role to restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35152873/restartmanager-causes-worker-role-to-restart/55308732#55308732)
- [What is the use of Repair option in a msi installer and what does it really do (internally)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613589/what-is-the-use-of-repair-option-in-a-msi-installer-and-what-does-it-really-do/49613785#49613785)
- [Disable MSI auto-repair on installed program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715332/disable-msi-auto-repair-on-installed-program/57717363#57717363)