# Why does my application triggers the Installer of another application?

Tags: vb6, installation, activex, windows-installer

When using a legacy VB6 application and opening some specific forms inside that application, the Windows Installer belonging to Microsoft Navision (which is installed on the same machine) pops-up like in the attached image.

It happens every time, but on this machine only.

The VB6 application has absolutely no relation with Navision!

What can be done to avoid this anomalous interaction between the two applications?

[image]

Comment: Most likely a COM control (ActiveX/OCX) used by both applications has been installed twice in different locations on disk and been "registered twice" from the different locations. Hence there are interfering COM registry entries that each application will try to put back to its own state on each instantiation of the control (the control is instantiated as you open the relevant VB form). I have written at length about [**MSI self-repair debugging here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is down to a corrupt windows installer database and your app is using some component that Microsoft Dynamics tried to install.
Your best bet is to remove and reinstall Microsoft Dynamics NAV, or use MSICUU to remove the "broken" package.

Update: MSICUU was [retired](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651) in preference to the [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) but I've not used this new utility.

Comment: Agree, uninstall & reinstall.  It is amazing how invasive the Windows Installer subsystem is, and how screwed up it can get sometimes.  Instead of dll hell we have MSI hell.

Comment: A lot of these Installer issues can be attributed to developer or administrator errors though, just like DLL Hell.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Not much you can do if some other bad install clips your required files.  Hard to code defensively against that!

Comment: That's where isolated assemblies can help.

Comment: tcarvin: self-heal should reinstall any files that have been 'clipped'