# Rebuilding Visual Studio Installer project, launches Visual Studio 2013 setup

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

I have recently upgraded to **Visual Studio 2013** (with the installer extension installed) from 2010, and now when I rebuild my Visual Studio Installer project, a Visual Studio 2013 setup window appears with the message:

**>"Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013"**

This screen stays up for about 1 minute then disappears, and the project then shows as rebuilding successfully.

I have set the output window to detailed and don't see anything obvious listed there. The last line before the setup window appears is

> Building file 'c:\ProjectPath\Debug\ProjectName.msi'...

After that the next lines talk about packing the necessary dll and files for the setup program.

I think that VS 2013 is missing a component that is required for setup projects but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try this serverfault post first: [Cleanup pending installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/264640/cleanup-pending-installation/276865#276865)
- Then try this comprehensive answer: [How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)

This should at least make you certain what component in the MSI that is triggering the self-repair. Most MSI packages can be repaired, but the Visual Studio installer works in mysterious ways. Give it a shot.

Comment: Didn't think of checking the Event Log. It showed that a folder was missing from the Microsoft.Net\Framework folder. Added that and issue has disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding as an answer here, as it might not be clear in comments above.

Based on @Glytzhkof's answer, checked the Event Log and found that a folder was missing.

Make sure the folder

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC

exists and the problem disappeared.

Comment: This worked for me, avoided the timely process of re-installing! (added it to both framework and framework64)