# Visual Studio Installer Project Extension running in VS 2017 Pro thinks it's running in VS 2013 Pro

Tags: visual-studio, installation, project, visual-studio-setup-proje

Got a big problem with the Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects Extension for Visual Studio 2017 Professional. I added a Visual Studio Installer Setup project to a solution and set it up the way it's basically supposed to be done (Primary Output in the Application Folder and an icon in the Desktop Folder is all that was needed). Then I right-clicked on the Setup project, clicked "Build" and then I get this:

> Please wait while Windows configures Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013.

And then it stalls indefinitely. I have to close Visual Studio in Task Manager to stop everything. What's more, I'm Visual Studio Professional 2017, not 2013. I used to have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, but I uninstalled it. What could possibly be causing the confusion?

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This is a good question and I'm also having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have also got Visual Studio 2013 installed, and that there is as conflict between 2013 and 2017 because that message is a Windows Installer repair of VS 2013. Something is happening during your build that requires the VS 2013 installation to be repaired. The Windows Event Log (Application) will have an MsiInstaller log entry saying which component appears to be broken. If you post that information there may be a clue to the problem. If you (for example) have manually removed anything that may belong to the VS 2013 installed product then that would cause the same kind of problem.

You have this similar problem:

[Rebuilding Visual Studio Installer project, launches Visual Studio 2013 seetup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254201/rebuilding-visual-studio-installer-project-launches-visual-studio-2013-seetup)

[Visual Studio 2015 msi build initiates another installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569268/visual-studio-2015-msi-build-initiates-another-installation)

When you say it stalls indefinitely, I would expect it to ask for the Visual Studio 2013 install image so that it can repair it. If you go to Programs&Features and manually repair VS 2013 it might fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also had Visual Studio 2013 installed as mentioned by @PhilDW.

Navigating to [Event Viewer](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/) → Windows Logs → Application I found loads of warnings:

> Detection of product '{9C593464-7F2F-37B3-89F8-7E894E3B09EA}', feature 'Visual_Studio_Professional_x86_enu', component '{E3FF99AA-78B9-4A06-8A74-869E9F65E1FE}' failed.  The resource 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC\' does not exist.

The key here being that the folder `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\URTInstallPath_GAC\` did not exist thanks to [an answer in the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254201/rebuilding-visual-studio-installer-project-launches-visual-studio-2013-setup#25255201) provided by @PhilDW.

Created the missing final folder `URTInstallPath_GAC` in the path mentioned and the installers now build *really fast* whereas before they used to take forever (sometimes literally!).