# Error when rebuild the setup project in c#

Tags: visual-studio-setup-proje

Im getting below error when im going to rebuild my setup project in visual studio 2015.Please advice to resolve this:

[image]

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254201/rebuilding-visual-studio-installer-project-launches-visual-studio-2013-seetup

Comment: What happens when you go to the file path specified in the lower window? The one that has Use Source above it.

Comment: nothing happend in the file path.there no path like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message means that the install of Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Integrated) is broken, so Windows is attempting to repair it. Also, it looks like it was installed from the internet, which resulted in the setup being performed from a temp folder that has since been deleted. It is always better to download the setup (such as the MSI file) and save it somewhere. It is also possible that the C:\Windows\installer folder has been damaged or has had files deleted because normally the repair would be performed from there, which might have been happening for a long time but you wouldn't have noticed until the cached MSI file was removed from /windows/installer.

The fix is to get hold of the exact same MSI file that was used to install VS 2010 Shell MSI file and save it somewhere, and browse to it when this happens again.

The cause might be a conflict between VS 2010 and VS 2015, or some removed or changed shared files. The application event log will have an MsiInstaller entry that says what is missing.