# How to understand which MSI file start

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have W8.1 and i need know which MSI file start when OS opening because installation is corrupted and all time i need press cancel. I want delete it to stop starting with Explorer.exe
I already tried to deactivate all process in tab process of Task Manager but don't work. 
There is a method to activate a log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check **the system's event log** to determine what product is triggering the installation or repair.

Please see these two posts for details:

- [How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair)
- [Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)
- [**Cleanup pending installation**](https://serverfault.com/questions/264640/cleanup-pending-installation/276865#276865)