# How do you disable a self repair

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have an MSI that performs a self pair when a new user logons and launches the exe, because of registry keys missing (the keys be pushed in using GPO).

tried DISABLEADVTSHORCUTS=1, cleared the key file for the exe component and cleared the property ReinstallModeText.  I don't want to delete the component guid in the component table as the installer does not register the component and the component cannot be removed.

Is there a easy clean way to disable/hide this feature?

Thanks

Comment: Self-repair running once to install per-user files is a common design. If you allow it to complete it might not happen for that user ever again. There is a large discussion of self-repair here: **[How can I determine what causes repeated Windows Installer self-repair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263)**

Answer (score 2):

Short of disabling the windows installer service (don't do it, I've seen people try.... DOH! ), you can never disable self repair.  It's a critical feature to windows installer and you should solve the root problem rather then trying to avoid the cure.

Comment: ..and there isn't any way to stop a user doing a repair manually either, if they can see the MSI file and right-click repair, or there is a repair option in Programs&Features.