# How do I uninstall Azure SDK for .NET 2.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, uninstallation, azure-sdk-.net

I downloaded pieces of Azure SDK for .NET 2.5 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44938), - "authoring tools", "Azure tools" and "libs for .net" packages and installed them one after another. Installation went successfully and Visual Studio 2012 even offered to migrate my .ccproj project afterwards.

The problem is they are not in "Add/Remove" programs list (SDK 1.8 components were in that list) so I have no idea how to start uninstalling the SDK.

How do I uninstall this stuff?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot find them in the "Add/Remove Programs" list because early SDK tools were called *Windows Azure Something* and were at the bottom of the list and newer SDK tools are called *Microsoft Azure Something* and are in the middle of the list.

Just order the list by "installed on" and you'll find them easily and can remove them.

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2015 Community. There are no Azure items in Add/Remove Programs and no uninstall option in Tools/Extensions and Updates.

**The solution is to go to `C:\Windows\Installer` and selecting Uninstall from the context menu on every `.msi` file that has "Azure" in the description. Works perfectly and every piece of azure trash is not in Visual Studio anymore.**

**Note:** `.msi` files have hash-like names in the `Installer` directory. To easily identify what's which `.msi` file, simply add the **Subject** column in Windows Explorer. It will show the description.

Comment: Pleasant benefits of removing all these extensions include more free hard drive space and a faster-starting Visual Studio.

Comment: What do you mean by the description? How to quickly identify those hash-like named `.msi` files?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy In Windows Explorer, you must display column "Subject" and word Azure must be contained in this column.

Comment: @Ondřej Great, it works. Thank you. I have added it to your answer.

Answer (score 13):

I also have same problem. I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Community(Update 2) and found a lot of Azure things there.
I tried removing them in the extensions window but even if I uninstalled them, they're still listed in the About window. It's like it just simply hidden not uninstalled.
Not to mention, Azure SDK also keeps asking for updates, and not exists in the extension list.

After some searching I found this tool. You can use this tool to remove the all the Azures. I've tried and it works. Now the Visual Studio starts faster too :D

https://github.com/tsasioglu/Total-Uninstaller

Answer (score 6):

To complete Ondřej's answer (I can't comment yet): since windows explorer doesn't show the description or allows to search for it, I opened a command-line in said folder and ran `findstr /I /M azure *.msi` to get the list of files containing "Azure". Then I checked each of the files in the resulting list manually to make sure I was related to Azure and I was done.

Answer (score 1):

[MyUninstaller](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/myuninst.html) has been around since 2003. It is free.
It is basically a more functional version of Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features. It lists a 10+ attributes for each msi; all of which are searchable, including Azure.

Under XP it was considerably faster, which is how I learned about it. It is very fast in "quick Mode", because it cache's the meta-data from the msi's in a single file (%APPDATA%\Roaming\NirSoft\MyUninst.ini). This is always going to be faster than opening and reading hundreds of MSI's.
F5 - refreshes the list, but is not usually necessary

I consider it safe and reliable since it does not actually "uninstall" anything. To uninstall it simply invokes the msi, which does the work.

Caveats:

- Deleting an entry does not uninstall and should only be used if the package was already uninstalled. (This is by design.)
- Uninstalling more than one package at the same time generally does
  not work, since msiexec does not allow that. (It is a harmless
  annoyance)
- The list may contain duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Microsoft tool to uninstall Azure exes which refuse to be uninstalled via the control panel: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058378/1072869)