# How to query InstallShield installer exe to get Product code without installing it?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield

My application is Install Shield based installer. My requirement is to silently install this installer in the build machine sliently by using /s command line argument.

To get this done we have to generate setup.iss file which will be used to install silently the installer. To automate the process of generating .iss file we need to populate the product code of the installer in the file.

Is there anyway to get the product code of an Install Shiled installer.exe without installing it just by querying it?

Answer (score 2):

You're problem is over complicated by the fact that you are using an InstallScript MSI project.  The main 'feature' of this project type is a rich UI.  But if your application is meant to be installed silently on a build server, who cares what the UI looks like?

Rewrite your installer as a Basic MSI  and use the standard command  msiexec /i foo.msi /qn REBOOT=R   and you won't need to do all this messing around with creating response files for install and uninstall.

I work for a company that uses SCCM to deploy installers to 300,000 machines and these response file driven installers always have a much higher failure rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform an administrative install ([`setup.exe /a ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694205/89999)), the .msi file will be extracted. From there you can query the .msi file for its product code using [Windows Installer APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372860.aspx) (see the Installer Database section).