# Silent install triggers another InstallShield

Tags: installation, installshield, packaging, silent

I'm trying to package up an install for deployment on the student laptops at my school.  What we do is set up a Powershell script to install it silently.  The application uses InstallShield.  That part I have handled just fine.

Unfortunately, half-way through the installation triggers another InstallShield wizard.  The executable for this doesn't seem to exist anywhere (so I assume it's buried within the primary executable).  This addition is something that I do want to install, but I have no idea how to go about it.

An internet search didn't yield anything useful for me.

Does anyone have any experience with anything like this?

Thanks in advance, guys and gals!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I ended up figuring out a solution (with some help from a co-worker).  What I ended up doing was running the silent install, and then when the new InstallShield popped up I went to the Task Manager so that I could find the location.  Once the location of the process was located, I copied all of the files from the temp directory folder they hid it in to the main file, and then went about writing the script to work from that location.  I was able to preempt the install of that InstallShield, and the program in question skipped that process making my install silent.  Hope this helps somebody one day.
The program in question was CAMWorks.

Comment: Never saw this back in the day. You can extract files from `setup.exe` files in a few ways. [The simplest overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681252/programmatically-extract-contents-of-installshield-setup-exe/8694205#8694205). And: [Extract MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512) (link overload).