# MSIExec via Powershell Install

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

Find the list of MSI Files from a directory and install on given PC remotely or locally . I want to be able to to run a script that will install 8 separate MSI files in a given directory 1 by 1. I found this script and think it work but i feel as if it is missing something right?

```ps
foreach($_msiFiles in 
($_msiFiles = Get-ChildItem $_Source -Recurse | Where{$_.Extension -eq ".msi"} |
 Where-Object {!($_.psiscontainter)} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName)) 
{
    msiexec /i $_msiFiles /passive
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the [**Windows Installer PowerShell Module**](https://github.com/heaths/psmsi) by [Heath Stewart](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/) - Microsoft Senior Software Engineer ([github](https://github.com/heaths))? And [for the record](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46221983/129130).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help you to understand what is going on here. I would write it something like this:

Declare source Directory:

```
$source = “\\path\to\source\folder”
```

Put each child .msi object into an array:

```
$msiFiles = Get-Childitem $source -File -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq “.msi”}
```

Iterate the array to run each .msi:

```
Foreach ($msi in $msiFiles) {

Msiexec /I “$($msi.FullName)” /passive

}
```

This is of course just an explanation of what you are doing. It does not include any error handling, checking for return codes, or remote command syntax, etc. etc.