# MSI Build uninstall- Installed directory not removing

Tags: build, msbuild, installshield, windows-installer

I created the MSI build package for our application. After this installation, we triggered another dependent driver software in the separate process in a committed event of Installer class like below,

Process.Start (" Path of driver software ")

We are facing an issue, installed directory ( It's empty ) folder is not removing while un-installing the same. Actually like installation, we triggered the un-installation of dependent driver software in the separate process by overriding the Uninstall method of installer class.

Anyone, please help me to overcome this issue? How could I remove the installed directory?

I can't change the installation procedure, since we are aware that we can't process another installation/un-installation when another one is going.

Comment: Can you post an install log? Which ever component the folder is associated with search for it in the log. It may provide clues as to why it's not removing it.

If you're looking for a brute-force fix you can add a custom action to the end of the installer, after InstallFinalize, that will delete the folder.

Comment: That's not the correct place to put the CA.  One could also try using the RemoveFile table rather then resorting to a custom action.  Solving the component rule problem would likely resolve the issue though.

Answer (score 1):

**You are running a non-MSI driver install EXE from within your MSI? Correct?** Or maybe it is an MSI wrapped in an EXE?

Do you have **Installshield Premier**? Could you use a **suite project** and install the EXE via the bootstrapper before (or after) the MSI install? I have honestly never used this feature, but running setups in sequence is what it is for. Embedded custom actions in MSI files kicking off EXE files are notoriously unreliable. This is - in my opinion - especially true if you are running with managed code as well (which I think you are).

In the long run managed code may yield safer custom action code (security-wise based on [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security)), but for now it seems to cause unwanted runtime dependencies - especially for very large-scale distribution (global distribution) targeting diverse Windows versions (Vista, 7, 8, 10).

I am told it takes a while to get used to Installshield's suite feature, but maybe it is better for you? You can run EXE files, MSI files, patches and zips in sequence. Some fiddling to define uninstall and upgrade behavior I guess and lots of testing. I am pretty sure corporate application packagers would be happy to see a suite rather than an MSI with lots of strange stuff embedded in it.

**UPDATE**: Once you have compiled a suite setup.exe file it can be extracted as described here: [Regarding silent installation using Setup.exe generated using Installshield 2013 (.issuite) project file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48976617/regarding-silent-installation-using-setup-exe-generated-using-installshield-2013/49011371#49011371)

[image: Installshield Suite Project]

---

Alternatively you could try to extract the setup.exe files for the driver setup and install the drivers as regular MSI components and run [DPinst.exe](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/svengruenitz/2008/07/02/driver-installation-and-updating-made-easy-dpinst-exe/) to install / uninstall the drivers (tool from [DIFx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ff544838(v=vs.80))). Also quite clunky - especially when you need to include uninstall.

Your driver setup likely uses DPInst.exe already. I would check if you can extract an MSI from the EXE and use it instead of the EXE to include in the suite project. Some hints for how to deal with setup.exe files (extraction, runtime paramenters etc...): [Extract MSI from EXE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe/24987512#24987512).

WiX has the [Driver element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/difxapp/driver.html) in one of its extensions to deal with driver installs. I have never had the chance to test it.