# How to install msi file in silent mode inside an InstallShield project

Tags: installshield, windows-installer, silent-installer

I have an InstallShield project which consists of two files and several folders,

MainSoftware.exe
AuxSoftware.msi
FolderA
FolderB
etc...

The main purpose of the project is just copying all of these files in the path specified by the user. It is very simple. However, after copying **AuxSoftware.msi** in the destination path, I need that a silent installation begins with this file. I know that a silent installation can be run by the following command:

msiexec /i AuxSoftware.msi /qn

But I don't know how to tell InstallShield that this command must be executed in the destination path after copying AuxSoftware.msi.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe check [Installshield Suite Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212599/129130) (not available in all editions of Installshield).

Answer (score 0):

You can only execute one installer at a time once it is in the InstallExecuteSequence. Stein has a very good, brief explanation in the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/175170/why-windows-installer-can-only-install-a-single-program-at-a-time).

I would suggest using a bootstrapper (setup.exe) that can install them in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions. I found a way. They call it "nested installations". I created a Custom Action having the second .msi or .exe installer I want to run after a specific point in the process of the main installation.

Comment: Nested installations kicked off by a custom action is a deprecated feature of Windows Installer. It is not recommended.

Comment: [Just to add a second link to this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/274675/20599).