# MSI Installer Keeps Failing to Install Adobe InCopy 32/64bit on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-installer, adobe, windows-server-2012-r2, adobe-incopy

Keep getting error 1603 when trying to install and msi package of Adobe InCopy CS6 onto windows server 2012 R2.

Already wiped the server and tried re-installation, same issue. Tried running various msiexec commands with many variations, all presenting the same issue.

```
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:22:981]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CreateShortcuts,Description=Creating shortcuts,Template=Shortcut: [1])
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:22:983]: Executing op: IconCreate(Icon=ARPPRODUCTICON.exe,Data=BinaryData)
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:22:985]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CADeploy,,)
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:22:987]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=CADeploy,ActionType=1025,Source=BinaryData,Target=runDeploymentManagerCA,CustomActionData=mode=install;sourceDir=C:\Users\cvautour\Desktop\x86\;installDir=;origDB=C:\Users\cvautour\Desktop\x86\install.msi)
MSI (s) (A8:00) [07:58:22:991]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI6A03.tmp, Entrypoint: runDeploymentManagerCA
CustomAction CADeploy returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:44:498]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:44:499]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:44:499]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 7:58:44: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
...
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:46:459]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:46:459]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (A8:9C) [07:58:46:461]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 7:58:46: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

Should be installing as it did on my other VM but just keeps failing on this one.

Comment: What .NET runtime version is on there? What kind of server is this? It is not a Terminal Server is it?

Comment: If you do an [administrative installation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751980/129130) (file extraction) of the MSI and put the MSI from the extracted files folder somewhere accessible we can take a better look. There seems to be a DLL custom action doing something funky. Could be a dependency issue or many other things.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Currently on .NET 4.6.2. I've got the extracted MSI and all its contents available for download here : [OneDrive](https://sunmediacorp-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/cvautour_postmedia_com/EmNzDJK801lAuEISwMR4oUEBN4wMpi-OhNjYiElOrhi-lA?e=RCXHVK)

Comment: Sorry, didn't get to look at this properly today. There is a DLL embedded in the Binary table (AdobeDeploymentManager). If you extract that DLL and run dependency walker on it the dependencies seem pretty minimal, so that does not seem to be the problem. You could double check on the box itself. Use Orca to extract the dll from the binary table. There also seems to be a driver installer exe in the binary table that installs some sort of optical driver? PXHelper from Prassi Europe? Does that ring a bell? I suppose you could try to disable that install, no time to test that now.

Comment: Got this sorted? Here are some further links for you: there does not seem to be a whole lot at: [itninja.com packaging tips](https://www.itninja.com/software) - normally a great source of real-world packaging tips for different software. Here is sort of [an escalation model of how I deal with bad or difficult deployment packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769767/129130). Get on the phone with them if you have a support agreement?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I'm facing the exact same issue... W10 VM installs just fine w/o any error and W7 VM msi-log looks like your's :/