# Installer failing with message "Error -2: The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

User is trying to install a installer, but it is failing to install with above message. It can be installed on other machine without an issue. Seems like an machine specific issue but I am not able to figure out the exact reason. I have created a log file with below cmd command.

```
"<<Installer Path>>" /v"/l*v c:\test.log"
```

I am seeing only one error in logs

> MSI (s) (3C:E0) [08:06:09:086]: MainEngineThread is returning 2

There is nothing descriptive in logs which could point to anything.

Do you know how log more logs? Or what does above message means?

Comment: Is this an old computer? Perhaps X86 hardware? Further: [Here is an answer that suggests issues with long file name support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/windows-7-installer-fails-with-the-installation/7d5f7df9-742b-47c1-8075-a92e973a5882). And there are [videos on youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxXcUH5mJMY) that touch the same - and also the re-registration of the Windows Installer Service.

Comment: Was the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

> [**Here is an older answer with information about MSI-logging**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54458890/129130).
>
> ***Top Tip***: Before trying anything else:
>
> ***`Reboot & try to install with a freshly generated local admin account`*** ([point 8 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130)).

---

***Debug Logging (Verbose)***: Advanced, slow logging for maximum details captured (from the linked answer above - it has a lot more detail):

```
msiexec.exe /i C:\Path\Your.msi /L*vx! C:\Your.log"
```

Search for ["**value 3**"](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) in the log file.

---

***Ideas?***: The first things that come to mind here are: **`1)`** Malware?, **`2)`** Anti-virus locking, **`3)`** Disk error or file system corruption?, **`4)`** Running without admin rights? or perhaps the most likely in many cases: **`5)`** Corrupted installation file.

---

***Links***: A couple of further links for your debugging.

- ***Recommended***: [Try to "eyeball" this list of likely deployment failure causes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60374125/129130).
- ***Details***: [Here in this rather crazy and organic link list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130), maybe check section "*Generic Tricks? - Consumer issues, failure to install setup.exe*".

Comment: I failed to mention this was an .exe (Created in Installsheild) and I am getting an error while running command with "x". Is there any other command to get more descriptive logging?

Comment: I would just [extract the MSI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24987512/129130) - then you can use a normal command line (like in answer above). You might want to install any required prerequisites manually first. Whatever is embedded in the setup.exe should come out with the MSI next to it. [Alternative answer on setup.exe extraction from Urman of Installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8694205/129130).

Comment: [Setup.exe and Update.exe Command-Line Parameters](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield25helplib/installshield25helplib.htm#helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm). Just try to extract and install in sequence yourself. My bet is you will see the problem disappear. Try extracting on another computer if the problem one fails to extract.