# ProgramFilesFolder Set to C:\ when using /a switch for msiexec

Tags: wix, group-policy, windows-installer

I have an .MSI installer that I created using WIX and works fine when opening the file from windows explorer or installing from a command window using msiexec /i. The problem is that I need to use /a to install it using a group policy when the computer turns on.

When using the /i option the ProgramFilesFolder value is set correctly to "C:\Program Files (x86)\".

When using the /a option the value of ProgramFilesFolder is set to "C:\", and then I get an error (on the Log) that says:

`The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2203. The arguments are: C:\Referrals.msi, -2147287035,`

Note: I am **not** running the .MSI file from "C:\"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
msiexec /a TARGETDIR="c:\temp\location" /passive
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have the [**msiexec.exe command line**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx) mixed up: **/a** is **[admin install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564619/what-is-the-purpose-of-administrative-installation-initiated-using-msiexec-a)**. This is essentially a command to create a **network installation point** with **extracted files** to use for installation on a lot of computers. This ensures the source files are available for patching, self-repair, repair, reinstall, etc...

To deal with **advertisement and group policy** you need to use [**these command line options**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Advertise). So a very basic operation would be advertise product to all users silently and write a log file:

```
msiexec.exe /JM "Installer.msi" /QN /L* "C:\msilog.log"
```