# silent install IBM data server client using response file, Anyone tried to install in D drive?

Tags: database, db2, windows-installer, silent-installer, ibm-data-db2

I am trying to install DB2 ibm data server client(version 11.1), silent install in my windows server. i am using response file for the installation. I gave the path in response file to install in D drive, but still it is installing in C drive only. the command i was using is: msiexec /i "MSI path" /q /l*v "log file path" RSP_FILE_PATH="response file path".

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:
[Installing Db2 products and features using a response](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/c0007502.html)

Comment: I have followed the same way before, to create a response file, but still my installation is not following the instructions that i pass in the response file. I am installing 11.1 version IBM Data server client.msi file. If you have installed 11.1 on your D drive please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Mark, your suggestion is useful. But i have changed my way of installation now, instead of using .msi file for installation, i am using setup.exe file now with the same response file. It worked now, i am able to install it in D drive. Thank you. Sorry i cannot mark you as an answer, because of the less reputation.

Answer (score -1):

> - Some notes on MSI customization in general below.
> - And a link to the most commonly used library of packaging tips contributed by packagers:
>     https://www.itninja.com/software-library/company/ibm

---

***Different Designs***: The exact mechanism used to redirect a folder like that depends on the design of the application and the setup from the vendor, they often do something very non-standard so reverse engineering their solution fully or slightly is usually neccessary.

***Itninja.com***: Maybe have a look if you can find the software here in the itninja.com "software tips" section: https://www.itninja.com/software-library/company/ibm - this is a collection of comments people have made who have packaged and deployed the software in question - either unsuccessfully or successfully. I can't really tell what the exact product name is, please check.

***Download***:  If you have a download link that is publicly accessible I can have a quick look at the MSI to determine how it is set up. Please be aware that it is much better to install an MSI directly via normal configuration mechanisms (setting public properties and / or creating a transform - [sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460379/how-to-parameterize-msi-file-from-electron-builder/55479296#55479296)) than to run a **`setup.exe`** with response file (which sometimes is the only possibility depending on the overall deployment design).

- [How to make better use of MSI files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458857/how-to-make-better-use-of-msi-files/1055861#1055861)

A couple of quick overviews:

- [How to parameterize msi file from electron builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55460379/how-to-parameterize-msi-file-from-electron-builder/55479296#55479296)
- [MSI Repackaging - free tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869537/msi-repackaging-free-tool/55034008#55034008)

And some further links for reference:

- [Change the value of a MSI property loaded from a DLL using a MSI transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761131/change-the-value-of-a-msi-property-loaded-from-a-dll-using-a-msi-transform/54769767#54769767)
- [How to run an installation in /silent mode with adjusted settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52327442/how-to-run-an-installation-in-silent-mode-with-adjusted-settings/52338626#52338626)

Comment: i am not using setup.exe. i am using .msi (example: IBM data server client.msi) windows installer file, along with response file which is .rsp (example: responsefile.rsp)extension.

Comment: OK, please have a look at that itninja software database linked to above first - might help.